# Convert java.util.Date to String

Tags: java, date, formatting, java.util.date

I want to convert a `java.util.Date` object to a `String` in Java.

The format is `2010-05-30 22:15:52`

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/format-date-in-java

Comment: @harschware FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: I recommend you don’t use and `Date` in 2019. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `Instant` or another class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 842, accepted):

Convert a **Date** to a **String** using [`DateFormat#format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format-java.util.Date-) method:

```
String pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";

// Create an instance of SimpleDateFormat used for formatting 
// the string representation of date according to the chosen pattern
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

// Get the today date using Calendar object.
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();        
// Using DateFormat format method we can create a string 
// representation of a date with the defined format.
String todayAsString = df.format(today);

// Print the result!
System.out.println("Today is: " + todayAsString);
```

From http://www.kodejava.org/examples/86.html

Comment: why use `Calendar` instead of plain `new Date()` ? Is there difference ?

Comment: Beware: SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840803/simpledateformat-thread-safety

Comment: The format in your answer does not match what the OP asked for. Also more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Calendar is an abstract class, Date is concrete. Date has no idea about TimeZone, Locale, or any of that good stuff that we all never use.

Comment: The `MM/dd/yyyy` format is stupid and broken. Do not use it. Always use `dd/MM/yyyy` or `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: @SystemParadox - It's stupid, but that doesn't make it pointless. I've been specifically asked to use it because it matches what people expect on reports. (I'd prefer `yyyy-MM-dd` everywhere, but what can you do?).

Comment: For other formats, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 262):

```
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String s = formatter.format(date);
```

Comment: come here for copy and paste, this answer save my time, Thanks and Upvoted.

Answer (score 71):

Commons-lang ***DateFormatUtils*** is full of goodies (if you have commons-lang in your classpath)

```
//Formats a date/time into a specific pattern
 DateFormatUtils.format(yourDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS");
```

Comment: Requires an additional `null` check.

Answer (score 25):

## tl;dr

```
myUtilDate.toInstant()  // Convert `java.util.Date` to `Instant`.
          .atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC )  // Transform `Instant` to `OffsetDateTime`.
          .format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME )  // Generate a String.
          .replace( "T" , " " )  // Put a SPACE in the middle.
```

> 2014-11-14 14:05:09

## java.time

The modern way is with the java.time classes that now supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

First convert your `java.util.Date` to an `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

Conversions to/from java.time are performed by new methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myUtilDate.toInstant();
```

Both your `java.util.Date` and `java.time.Instant` are in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). If you want to see the date and time as UTC, so be it. Call `toString` to generate a String in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
String output = instant.toString();
```

> 2014-11-14T14:05:09Z

For other formats, you need to transform your `Instant` into the more flexible [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

> odt.toString(): 2020-05-01T21:25:35.957Z

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/2Vm2O5).

To get a String in your desired format, specify a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). You could specify a custom format. But I would use one of the predefined formatters ([`ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)), and replace the `T` in its output with a SPACE.

```
String output = odt.format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME )
                   .replace( "T" , " " );
```

> 2014-11-14 14:05:09

By the way I do not recommend this kind of format where you purposely lose the [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) or time zone information. Creates ambiguity as to the meaning of that string’s date-time value.

Also beware of data loss, as any fractional second is being ignored (effectively truncated) in your String’s representation of the date-time value.

To see that same moment through the lens of some particular region’s [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time), apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

> zdt.toString():  2014-11-14T14:05:09-05:00[America/Montreal]

To generate a formatted String, do the same as above but replace `odt` with `zdt`.

```
String output = zdt.format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME )
                   .replace( "T" , " " );
```

> 2014-11-14 14:05:09

If executing this code a very large number of times, you may want to be a bit more efficient and avoid the call to `String::replace`. Dropping that call also makes your code shorter. If so desired, specify your own formatting pattern in your own `DateTimeFormatter` object. Cache this instance as a constant or member for reuse.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" );  // Data-loss: Dropping any fractional second.
```

Apply that formatter by passing the instance.

```
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time.

Comment: Here are code examples of formatting with Java 8 Time API: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43457343/603516

Comment: this code does not work
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC );
    odt.toString(): 2014-11-14T14:05:09+00:00
Is there a new Java 8 code to have the same format 2014-11-14T14:05:09+00:00  ? Thank you

Comment: @BobBolden You are correct, `Z` is used instead of `+00:00` by default. I fixed the Answer, thanks.  FYI, those mean the same thing: `Z`, pronounced “Zulu” means an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds, the same as `+00:00`. The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard supports both styles.

Comment: @BasilBourque sorry, this is unclear. I have Java 8 and there is no instant.atOffset() at all. Could you please advice what should be the correct code for Java 8 to have exactly the same format 2014-11-14T14:05:09+00:00 without instant.atOffset() ? I'm a bit lost :(

Comment: @BobBolden There is indeed an `atOffset` method on `Instant` class in Java 8. See Javadoc:  [`Instant::atOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#atOffset-java.time.ZoneOffset-). In Java 8, a call like `Instant.now().atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ).toString()` will run. Check your `import` statements. Verify your IDE/project is set to run Java 8 or later rather than an earlier version of Java. See the code run live at IdeOne.com: https://ideone.com/2Vm2O5

Answer (score 24):

Altenative one-liners in plain-old java:

```
String.format("The date: %tY-%tm-%td", date, date, date);

String.format("The date: %1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td", date);

String.format("Time with tz: %tY-%<tm-%<td %<tH:%<tM:%<tS.%<tL%<tz", date);

String.format("The date and time in ISO format: %tF %<tT", date);
```

This uses [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dt) and [relative indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891175/what-about-if-youve-got-the-same-parameter-multiple-times-in-string-format/41150461#41150461) instead of `SimpleDateFormat` which is [not thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021151/java-dateformat-is-not-threadsafe-what-does-this-leads-to), btw.

Slightly more repetitive but needs just one statement. 
This may be handy in some cases.

Comment: This is (in)genius. Much better performance for constrained environments

Comment: For beginners: `import java.util.Date;` and declare `Date date= new Date();` to make this code example complete. If it's not obvious from the question already.

Answer (score 9):

Why don't you use Joda (org.joda.time.DateTime)?
It's basically a one-liner.

```
Date currentDate = GregorianCalendar.getInstance().getTime();
String output = new DateTime( currentDate ).toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

// output: 2014-11-14 14:05:09
```

Comment: I suggest passing a DateTimeZone as well, rather than assign the JVM’s current default time zone to the `DateTime` object. `new DateTime( currentDate , DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) )`

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you are looking for [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Format: yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss

Comment: Does the "kk" do anything special? I think Eric wants it in 24-hour time.

Comment: Yes, the hour in day (1-24), but this is likely not what the OP needs. `HH` (0-23) is more common.

Comment: @Cahrlie Salts kk goes from 1-24, where HH goes from 0-23, and it probably was a bit presumptuous of me to assume he wanted 1-24 @BalusC The DateFormat object both parses and formats.

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of your last comment. My comment was to Charlie.

Comment: I'm used to .Net formats, where HH is 24-time, and hh is am/pm. Hence the head-scratching.

Comment: @BalusC Before it was edited or removed, it was mentioned that my solution did not solve the OP's question.

Answer (score 7):

In single shot ;)

**To get the Date**

```
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",   Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
```

**To get the Time**

```
String time = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
```

**To get the date and time**

```
String dateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", Locale.getDefaut()).format(new Date());
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 5):

```
public static String formateDate(String dateString) {
    Date date;
    String formattedDate = "";
    try {
        date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",Locale.getDefault()).parse(dateString);
        formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy",Locale.getDefault()).format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return formattedDate;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are examples of using new [Java 8 Time API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) to format [legacy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/legacy.html) `java.util.Date`:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS Z")
        .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    String utcFormatted = formatter.format(date.toInstant()); 

    ZonedDateTime utcDatetime = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    String utcFormatted2 = utcDatetime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS Z"));
    // gives the same as above

    ZonedDateTime localDatetime = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    String localFormatted = localDatetime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);
    // 2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]

    String nowFormatted = LocalDateTime.now().toString(); // 2007-12-03T10:15:30.123
```

It is nice about `DateTimeFormatter` that it can be efficiently cached as it is thread-safe (unlike `SimpleDateFormat`).

[List of predefined fomatters and pattern notation reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#predefined).

Credits:

[How to parse/format dates with LocalDateTime? (Java 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463062/how-to-parse-format-dates-with-localdatetime-java-8)

[Java8 java.util.Date conversion to java.time.ZonedDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25376242/java8-java-util-date-conversion-to-java-time-zoneddatetime)

[Format Instant to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229124/format-instant-to-string)

[What's the difference between java 8 ZonedDateTime and OffsetDateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30234594/whats-the-difference-between-java-8-zoneddatetime-and-offsetdatetime)

Answer (score 4):

If you only need the time from the date, you can just use the feature of String.

```
Date test = new Date();
String dayString = test.toString();
String timeString = dayString.substring( 11 , 19 );
```

This will automatically cut the time part of the String and save it inside the `timeString`.

Comment: This may break with different locale.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to use it is as following:

```
currentISODate = new Date().parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", "2013-04-14T16:11:48.000");
```

where "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" is the format of the reading date

output: Sun Apr 14 16:11:48 EEST 2013

Notes: HH vs hh
- HH refers to 24h time format
- hh refers to 12h time format

Comment: The question is about opposite conversion.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Date d = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    System.out.println(form.format(d));
    String str = form.format(d); // or if you want to save it in String str
    System.out.println(str); // and print after that
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    Date today = cal.getTime();
    DateFormat df7 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    try {           
        String str7 = df7.format(today);
        System.out.println("String in yyyy-MM-dd format is: " + str7);          
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Or a utility function

```
public String convertDateToString(Date date, String format) {
    String dateStr = null;
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);

    try {
        dateStr = df.format(date);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dateStr;
}
```

From [Convert Date to String in Java](http://javabycode.com/java-core/java-common/convert-date-to-string-in-java.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String date = "2010-05-30 22:15:52";
    java.util.Date formatedDate = sdf.parse(date); // returns a String when it is parsed
    System.out.println(sdf.format(formatedDate)); // the use of format function returns a String
```

Answer (score 1):

**One Line option**

This option gets a easy one-line to write the actual date.

> Please, note that this is using `Calendar.class` and `SimpleDateFormat`, and then it's not
>   logical to use it under Java8.

```
yourstringdate =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: (1) The answer is wrong (I just got `2019-20-23 09:20:22` — month 20??) (2) I can’t see that the answer provides anything that isn’t already covered in other answers. (3) Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Yeah.... I did a mistake and forget to correct it. I added it at quickly way, and didn´t remember .. sorry!! and thanks for your comments guys

Comment: @OleV.V. Not everybody has access to the Modern Java data and time api...... so ... It´s also valid this answer...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If you want to provide an answer for Java 5, or for Java 6 and 7 without any external dependency, very fine, that’s welcome, only please make explicit that that is what you are doing. And your answer is still wrong, you will get surprises around New Year.

Comment: Hahahaha, I think I have not a good day. I just wrote it down quickly to complete this page, as I thought mi line was ok, and as I said I corrected it in my code, but not here.... hahhaha Thanks for the point @OleV.V.

Answer (score 1):

```
Date date = new Date();
String strDate = String.format("%tY-%<tm-%<td %<tH:%<tM:%<tS", date);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include **timezone** information in the resultant string:

```
public String getFormattedDate(Date date) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    return sdf.format(date);
}
```

Comment: Suggesting the use of the terribly flawed legacy date-time classes in 2023 is poor advice.