# Do I have to specify a variable for each identical argument in String.format?

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

```
String hello = "Hello";

String.format("%s %s %s %s %s %s", hello, hello, hello, hello, hello, hello);

hello hello hello hello hello hello
```

Does the `hello` variable need to be repeated multiple times in the call to the format method or is there a shorthand version that lets you specify the argument once to be applied to all of the `%s` tokens?

Answer (score 343):

From [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax):

> - The format specifiers for general, character, and numeric types have the following syntax:
>
>   ```
>   %[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion
>   ```
>
> The optional *argument_index* is a decimal integer indicating the position of the argument in the argument list. The first argument is referenced by `"1$"`, the second by `"2$"`, etc.

```
String.format("%1$s %1$s %1$s %1$s %1$s %1$s", hello);
```

Answer (score 95):

Another option is to use *relative indexing*: The format specifier references the same argument as the last format specifier.

For example:

```
String.format("%s %<s %<s %<s", "hello")
```

results in `hello hello hello hello`.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dpos

Answer (score 27):

You need to use the index argument `%[argument_index$]` as the following:

```
String hello = "Hello";
String.format("%1$s %1$s %1$s %1$s %1$s %1$s", hello);
```

Result: `Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello`

Answer (score 6):

One common case for reusing an argument in `String.format` is with a separator (e.g. `";"` for CSV or tab for console).

```
System.out.println(String.format("%s %2$s %s %2$s %s %n", "a", ";", "b", "c"));
// "a ; ; ; b"
```

This isn't the desired output. `"c"` doesn't appear anywhere.

You need to use the separator first (with `%s`) and only use the argument index (`%2$s`) for the following occurences :

```
System.out.println(String.format("%s %s %s %2$s %s %n", "a", ";", "b", "c"));
//  "a ; b ; c"
```

Spaces are added for readability and debugging. Once the format appears to be correct, spaces can be removed in the text editor:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%s%s%s%2$s%s%n", "a", ";", "b", "c"));
// "a;b;c"
```