# Change digits within a String incrementally in Java

Tags: java

I have a String with digits at index 4 and 18. I need to print the String to the Java console such that the number increments by one until it reaches the number 40.

**String:**

```
String a = "AAA_0_BBB_CCC(DDD_0_EEE)" ;
```

**Desired Output in Console:**

```
AAA_1_BBB_CCC(DDD_1_EEE)
AAA_2_BBB_CCC(DDD_2_EEE)
AAA_3_BBB_CCC(DDD_3_EEE)
.
.
.
AAA_40_BBB_CCC(DDD_40_EEE)
```

My program (see below) prints digits from 0 to 9. But I didn't know how to continue the loop with double digits (11 to 40). I can rewrite the program for each index(4,5,19,20) but i was wondering if there was a simpler way to handle it.

**My program for changing at index 4 and 18 with one digit:**

```
public static void main(String[] args){
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer( a );
String a = "AAA_0_BBB_CCC(DDD_0_EEE)" ;
for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++){
//make i a character j
String k = Integer.toString(i);
char j = k.charAt(0);
//replace index position 4 and 18
buf.setCharAt( 4, j );
buf.setCharAt( 18, j );
String z = buf.toString( );
System.out.println(z);
}
```

Comment: Is the rest of the string (AAA, BBB and so on) is constant, or does it change?

Comment: You can use String.format

Comment: Are both numbers guaranteed to be same or is input like `AAA_0_BBB_CCC(DDD_2_EEE)` possible? If it is possible then what should be final result? Should it be `AAA_38_BBB_CCC(DDD_40_EEE)` or `AAA_40_BBB_CCC(DDD_42_EEE)`

Comment: yes it changes, the actual string that I am working on is a long query in SQL that needs to be repeated. The string I used in this question was for ease of use. And the numbers has to be the same in each string. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a format string and substituion parameters to `System.out.printf` function:

```
for( int i = 0; i <= 40; i++ ) {
    System.out.printf("AAA_%d_BBB_CCC(DDD_%<d_EEE)%n", i);
}
```

The `%<d` specification is using the prior argument, so you don't need to pass the parameter `i` twice.  The `%n` is the platform-dependent newline.

Comment: and %n too, I was missing that :)

Answer (score 5):

What you need can easily be achieved with [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))

```
for (int i = 0; i<= 40; i++){
    String str = String.format("AAA_%d_BBB_CCC(DDD_%d_EEE)", i, i);
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

You could even simplify the call a little by using [argument index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6891209/2032064):

```
String.format("AAA_%1$d_BBB_CCC(DDD_%1$d_EEE)", i);
```

In general, it is a good idea to use `String.format()` (or `System.out.printf()` as Andreas mentioned) whenever you need to create a string out of non-string values. Check out [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) for documentation of the format string syntax.

---

One more thing: I see you are using `StringBuffer` in your code. Consider using `StringBuilder` which is slightly faster (and not thread-safe). Using `StringBuilder`, what you need to achieve could look like

```
String str = new StringBuilder().append("AAA_").append(i).append("_BBB_CCC(DDD_").append(i).append("_EEE)").toString();
```

Or you could even use simple

```
String str = "AAA_" + i + "_BBB_CCC(DDD_" + i + "_EEE)";
```

Java compiler is smart enough to insert `StringBuilder` where concatenating longer several strings automatically.

Comment: You can combine the lines: `System.out.printf("AAA_%d_BBB_CCC(DDD_%d_EEE)%n", i, i);`

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about the format method in String. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following logic for formatted output.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    for(int i = 1; i<= 40; i++){
        System.out.printf("AAA_%d_BBB_CCC(DDD_%d_EEE)%n", i, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i wasn't aware of printf() either. This also works.

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions is a good choice if the string is dynamic and the numeric places have a pattern.

```
String a = "AAA_0_BBB_CCC(DDD_0_EEE)";
for (int i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
    System.out.println(a.replaceAll("_0_", "_" + i + "_"));
}
```

This can be optimized for performance:

```
String a = "AAA_0_BBB_CCC(DDD_0_EEE)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("_0_").matcher(a);
for (int i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
    System.out.println(m.replaceAll("_" + i + "_"));
}
```

Can even be simplified if you're sure there are no `0` digits in he rest of the string.

```
String a = "AAA_0_BBB_CCC(DDD_0_EEE)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("0").matcher(a);
for (int i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
    System.out.println(m.replaceAll(String.valueOf(i)));
}
```