# More on Dates in Java

Tags: java, date, format

I think I've pretty well got a hold on Dates now. So, I created a new object in a class and I assigned it a Date property, and I told it to print the Date property. It does, but just like it would normally do in C#, it presents a Date and a Time. But in C#, you can change that by something like this:

```
 Console.WriteLine("myDate = {0}:d", myDate);
```

And the :d changes it to just a normal Date format without the time. Is there any similar way to do that in Java?

Comment: You can use [`MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html), or the [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dt) syntax which is used in `PrintStream.printf()` and `String.format()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683728/convert-java-util-date-to-string

Comment: Follow the link that @kaya gave, you need a DateFormat object to parse the date in *any* format that you want!

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

```java
myJavaUtilDate                                   // Legacy class. Terribly flawed. Avoid.
    .toInstant()                                 // Convert from legacy class to modern `java.time.Instant` class.
    .atZone ( ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) )  // Apply a time zone to shift from UTC. Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object. 
    .toLocalDate()                               // Extract date portion, ignoring time-of-day and time zone. Returns a `LocalDate` object. 
    .format(                                     // Generate text representing the content of a `java.time` object.
        DateTimeFormatter
            .ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.FULL ) // Automatically localize.
            .withLocale( Locale.GERMANY )        // Use `Locale` to specify human language and cultural norms.
    )                                            // Returns a `String` object. Send to console with `System.out.println( … )`.
```

### Avoid legacy date-time classes

You may be using the terribly flawed `java.util.Date` class. This is one of the legacy date-time classes now supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

A `java.util.Date`, despite its poorly chosen name, represents a point on the timeline, a moment. This class was replaced by `java.time.Instant`.

### `Instant`

To convert, use the new `to`/`from` methods added the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

### `ZoneId`

Neither `java.util.Date` nor `java.time.Instant` have a date. Remember that for any given moment, **the date varies** around the globe by time zone. It is “tomorrow” in Tokyo Japan while simultaneously “yesterday” in Toledo Ohio US.

To determine a date for any moment, you must **specify the time zone** by which you want to perceive a calendar.

```
ZoneId zTokyo = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

Apply that `ZoneId` object to the `Instant` object to instantiate a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtTokyo = instant.atZone( zTokyo ) ;
```

### `LocalDate`

Now extract the date portion.

```
LocalDate ld = zdtTokyo.toLocalDate() ;
```

### Generating text

You can generate text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
String output = ld.toString() ;
```

You can generate text in localized format. Specify a `Locale` to determine the human language and cultural norms.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;
DateTimeFormatter f = 
    DateTimeFormatter
        .ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.FULL ) 
        .withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = ld.format( f ) ;
```

### Console

To write to the console in Java, use the automatically instantiated object named `System.out`.

```
System.out.println( output ) ;
```