# Date class in java

Tags: java, date, epoch

I am writing a java program to print either the milliseconds, seconds or days since 1/1/1970 or the current date depending on user input.  I have it all written but for some reason it won't execute and I am really confused as to why.  I am pretty sure it has something to do with the `Date` class.  Did I import it correctly? I am new to java so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
package com.company;


import java.util.Date;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //get string args
        String input = args[0];

        //parse ints from string
        int command = Integer.parseInt(input);
        Date structDate = new Date();
        long milliseconds = structDate.getTime();
        long seconds = milliseconds / 1000;
        long days = seconds / 86400;

        switch (command) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("milliseconds since January 1, 1970:" + milliseconds);
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.println("seconds since January 1, 1970:" + seconds);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("days since January 1, 1970:" + days);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("current Date and Time:" + structDate);
                break;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "wont execute". what errors do you get?

Comment: Are you passing the argument to the program while running? Are you getting any Exception?

Comment: I get this exception:

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.date.Main`

Comment: I compiled you class and ran it and it worked: seconds since January 1, 1970:1431925045

Comment: How are you trying to execute the program?  That sounds like you're passing in the wrong fully-qualified class name to the java command (assuming you're running it by hand in the console).

Comment: agree with 1337joe - you need to run com.company.Main

Comment: I'm trying to execute this in IntelliJ using the "program arguments" under Edit Configurations to pass in the arguments

Comment: hmm. i just used intellij too. did you build an earlier version where the package name was java.util.date? because it should want to run com.company.Main

Comment: this behaviour would make sense if you used "package java.util.date" assuming this is how the import works. then credited the intellij "Run" configuration, then edited the code as above.  you should just be able to edit the Main class section of the configuration to be: com.company.Main - select Run / Edit Configurations

Comment: Please show the full command you are using to run it. I suspect it's `java java.util.date.Main` when it should be `java com.company.Main`

Answer (score -2):

### Your code works

Your code does indeed run successfully. See this slightly modified version [run at Ideone](https://ideone.com/KVpVwP).

```java
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        //get string args
        List.of( "0" , "1" , "2" , "3" ).forEach( Ideone :: parseAndPrint ) ;
    }
    
    static void parseAndPrint( final String input )
    {
        //parse ints from string
        int command = Integer.parseInt(input);
        Date structDate = new Date();
        long milliseconds = structDate.getTime();
        long seconds = milliseconds / 1000;
        long days = seconds / 86400;

        switch (command) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("milliseconds since January 1, 1970:" + milliseconds);
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.println("seconds since January 1, 1970:" + seconds);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("days since January 1, 1970:" + days);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("current Date and Time:" + structDate);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

```
milliseconds since January 1, 1970:1708669903173
seconds since January 1, 1970:1708669903
days since January 1, 1970:19776
current Date and Time:Fri Feb 23 06:31:43 GMT 2024
```

### Passing arguments to your program launch

So your problem must lay in that first part, passing the argument from launching the Java app. As others commented, you must execute the name of the class that contains the `main` method while passing your intended argument.

First compile.

```bash
javac Main.java
```

Then run while passing an argument as seen next. The `java` is the tool to launch a [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine). The `-cp` declares the [classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath). The `.` says the [*current working directory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) should be added to the classpath via the `-cp` before it. The `Main` is the name of our class containing a `main` method to be executed by the JVM. The `"2"` is the argument to be passed from the console to our app as an array of `String` objects, an array of one element in our case, the `args` variable seen in our code.

```bash
java -cp . Main "2"
```

You mentioned in a Comment that your are using the [*IntelliJ*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment). All IDEs let you configure a runtime environment where arguments can be passed in as if they were coming from a launch on a command-line console. For *IntelliJ* in particular, see: [*How do you input command line arguments in IntelliJ IDEA?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2066307/642706).

You can test to see if you do have incoming arguments from the console. The top of your code should throw an exception such as `IllegalArgumentException`. You could print a warning to the console.

```
if( args.length == 0 ) 
{
    System.out.println( "Received no arguments from the console." ) ;
    throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Expected exactly one argument, but received none from console." ) ;
}
```

For more info, see the Question [*How to execute a java .class from the command line*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1279542/642706).

Tip: Notice in the code above how we separated the business logic (reacting to an input) from the `main` method. The purpose of the `main` method is merely setting up your app to execute, such as managing the incoming `args` arguments. Your business logic should live elsewhere. By being separate, you can test the `parseAndPrint` method without need to actually execute the app with console arguments (more convenient while developing).

Writing and running such brief code will be easier in a future version of Java. See [*JEP 463: Implicitly Declared Classes and Instance Main Methods (Second Preview)*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/463). See also [*JEP 330: Launch Single-File Source-Code Programs*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/330) and [*JEP 458: Launch Multi-File Source-Code Programs*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/458).

In addition, your date-time code should be re-worked. Read on.

### Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using the terribly flawed `java.util.Date` class. That is one of the legacy date-time classes supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

If handed a `java.util.Date` object, convert to its replacement, `java.time.Instant`.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

### Current moment

To capture the current moment as seen with an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds, use `java.time.Instant.now()`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

You asked:

> print either the milliseconds, seconds or days since 1/1/1970 or the current date depending on user input.

### Milliseconds

That class represents a moment as a count of whole seconds, plus a fractional second as a count of nanoseconds, since the first moment of 1970 UTC (1970-01-01T00:00Z). To extract the count as milliseconds:

```
long millisecondsSince1970Utc = instant.toEpochMilli() ;
```

Be aware of data loss with that line above. You are ignoring any microseconds and nanoseconds that may be contained in that `Instant` object.

### Seconds

To get count of whole seconds since first moment of 1970 in UTC:

```
long secondsSince1970Utc = instant.getEpochSecond() ;
```

Again, possible data loss as we are ignoring possible milliseconds, microseconds, and nanoseconds in that `Instant` object.

Also notice one of the few flaws in the *java.time* API: That `getEpochSecond` method should have been named `toEpochSecond`. As a getter, that name unnecessarily reveals an implementation detail that a count of whole seconds is stored inside that object.

### Days

To get a count of days is more complicated. Do you mean “days” in terms of 24-hour chunks of time? Or do you mean “days” as in days on the year-month calendar?

#### 24-hour chunks

For a count of 24 hour chunks, use `Duration` class. This class represents a span of time unattached to the timeline.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( Instant.EPOCH , instant ) ;
```

Ask for a count of 24-hour chunks of time.

```
long chunksOf24HoursSinceStartOf1970Utc = d.toDays() ;
```

#### Calendar days

For a count of calendar days, we must apply a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. It is “tomorrow” in Tokyo Japan while simultaneously “yesterday” in Toledo Ohio US.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
```

Apply that time zone to our `Instant` object to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Now we can get a count of calendar days elapsed by way of the `Period` class.

```
Period p = Period.between( Instant.EPOCH.atZone( z ) , zdt ) ;
int calendarDaysSinceStartOf1970Utc = p.getDays() ;
```

---

To see similar coverage on these topics, see [my other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78044574/642706).

Comment: All true but it doesn't explain the OP's error.

Comment: @user207421 Very well, added another section up top to address the likely failure to pass arguments when app is launched.