# How to retrieve chosen date from JDatechooser?

Tags: java, jdatechooser

I am using Eclipse to do a college project on Java. I realized that java does not have a built in date selector like C#, so I downloaded and added `JDateChooser`. I tried to retrieve the chosen date but it failed:

```
 String Date = dateChooser.getDate(); //I want to the date to be retrieved as string
```

Any ideas? Is there some kind of initialization that I must do?

Comment: I don't think getDate returns a String

Comment: Okay then, what data Type does it return? And how do I get the date from it?

Comment: It might also help if you could tell us which JDateChooser you're using

Comment: Like most languages, time in Java is representation of a period of time since a fixed moment in time. In Java, this is represented by the number of milliseconds since the unix epoch and is represented by the java.util.Date class

Comment: I did a google search and found no less then 4 different versions. Where did you download it from?

Comment: I downloaded it from toedtr

Comment: Good, because that's the JavaDocs I referenced in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve the date that the user selected by calling `getDate()`, which returns a `Date` object. Then convert that object into a `String` by calling `SimpleDateFormat.format()`:

```
Date              d;
SimpleDateFormat  sdf;
String            s;

d = dateChooser.getDate();                      // Date selected by user
sdf = SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");  // Or whatever format you need
s = sdf.format(d);                              // Viola
```

**See also**: [Question 5683728](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683728/convert-java-util-date-to-string)

Comment: Hello, and thanks a lot. Everytime I try that, I get an error on dateChooser.getDate(). It says that "dateChooser cannot be resolved" although I am sure that the name in the design is "dateChooser"

Comment: I also made sure that it is added to the build path, but I still have the error and cannot run it. Please help me. What are the things that I should do before I am able to use datechooser? I might be missing something

Answer (score 0):

If I have the right component, the [Java Docs](http://max-server.myftp.org/jcalendar/ibuild/dist/doc/api/com/toedter/calendar/JDateChooser.html#getDate%28%29) show that the `getDate` method returns `Date`

> getDate
>
> public java.util.Date getDate()
>  Returns the date. If the
>   JDateChooser is started with a null date and no date was set by the
>   user, null is returned.
>  Returns:
>  the current date

Answer (score 0):

String dob =new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(jDateChooser1.getDate());

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Today no one needs `SimpleDateFormat` nor `Date`. We should all be using [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also does your answer provide anything substantial that isn’t already in the accepted answer?