# How to covert Joda-Time's DateTimeFormat.forStyle() to JSR 310 JavaTime?

Tags: migration, java-8, jodatime, java-time

I working on convertion Grails Joda-Time plugin to [JavaTime](https://github.com/stokito/grails-java-time).

And I've old Joda time code like this:

```
    def style
    switch (type) {
        case LocalTime:
            style = '-S'
            break
        case LocalDate:
            style = 'S-'
            break
        default:
            style = 'SS'
    }
    Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.locale
    return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(style, locale).withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.LENIENT)
```

How can I conver it to JSR 310?
I can't find anything similar to method [forStyle(String style)](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/src-html/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#line.193) which accepts style.

**UPD**
I found workaround:

```
        Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.locale
        DateTimeFormatter formatter
        switch (type) {
            case LocalTime:
                formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.SHORT).withLocale(locale)
                break
            case LocalDate:
                formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT).withLocale(locale)
                break
            default:
                formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.SHORT).withLocale(locale)
        }
        return formatter
```

But it fails of `Instant` type. Spock spec to reproduce:

```
def 'Instant locale formatting'() {
    given:
    Instant inst = Instant.ofEpochMilli(92554380000L)
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.SHORT).withLocale(UK)
    expect:
    formatter.format(inst) == "07/12/72 05:33"
}
```

This test fails with error:

```
java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: DayOfMonth
    at java.time.Instant.getLong(Instant.java:603)
    at java.time.format.DateTimePrintContext$1.getLong(DateTimePrintContext.java:205)
    at java.time.format.DateTimePrintContext.getValue(DateTimePrintContext.java:298)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$NumberPrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2543)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$CompositePrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2182)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$LocalizedPrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:4350)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$CompositePrinterParser.format(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2182)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.formatTo(DateTimeFormatter.java:1744)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.format(DateTimeFormatter.java:1718)
```

So, why formatter can't format `Instant`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The methods `ofLocalizedDate()`, `ofLocalizedTime()` and `ofLocalizedDateTime()` provide the localized formats.

To format an `Instant` a time-zone is required. This can be added to the formatter using `withZone()`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter =
    DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.SHORT)
                     .withLocale(UK)
                     .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Without the zone, JSR-310 formatter has no knowledge of how to convert the instant to human date-time fields.

Comment: I found a strange issue, possible a bug 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27488494/how-to-parse-string-with-date-but-without-time-in-local-format-to-zoneddatetime

Answer (score 1):

JSR 310 has other ways to replace style: `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime()`, `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate()` and `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime()`

Other problem is that `Instant` type can't be formatted 
[Format Instant to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229124/format-instant-to-string)