# Formatting Instant to String with specific pattern

Tags: java

I'm trying to format `Instant` to `String` with a specific format. Based on the question here [Format Instant to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229124/format-instant-to-string), I'm doing this -

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern("YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm'Z'")
        .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);

// Fails for current time with error 'Field DayOfYear cannot be printed as the 
// value 148 exceeds the maximum print width of 2'
LocalDateTime 
      .ofInstant(Instant.now(), ZoneOffset.UTC)
      .format(DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);

// But works for smaller values of Instant    
LocalDateTime
     .ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(604800000), ZoneOffset.UTC)
     .format(DATE_TIME_FORMATTER));
```

Any suggestions on why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: D is not the same as d.

Comment: oh man..just wasted a lot of time. Thnx!

Comment: Cant they have a better exception trace :-(

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Pattern `YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm'Z'` is wrong:

- `YYYY` - week-based-year       **wrong: use `uuuu` *year***
- `MM` - month-of-year
- `DD` - day-of-year       **wrong: use `dd` *day-of-month***
- `hh` - clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-12)       without AM/PM you probably want `HH` *hour-of-day (0-23)*
- `mm` - minute-of-hour

It's weird, because you even referenced a link that had the right pattern characters. Unless of course you thought upper- vs lower-case didn't matter, but if so, how did you think `MM` (month) vs `mm` (minute) worked?

You might want to actually read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns).

Comment: what is the difference between `yyyy` and `uuuu`

Comment: @Sumit See last line of answer: *"You might want to actually read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns)"*. --- Or read the answers to this question: [`uuuu` versus `yyyy` in `DateTimeFormatter` formatting pattern codes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41177442/5221149)

Comment: Yes, reading the documentation is actually what confused me. I couldn't understand why `yyyy` is _wrong_ and why `uuuu` is _correct_.

It says `u` is `year and `y` is `year-of-era` and then it gives the exact same example: `2004; 04` for both, based on that, I have no idea what is the difference between the two.

The other SO answer link that you provided, you seem to have a contradictory opinion with your `Julius Caesar` example and using `y GG` seems to be better than using `u` to avoid negative years. But, the other answers written there were helpful so, Thanks!

Comment: @Sumit It's not a contradiction, it's an example of the difference. If you did Julius Caesar example with `y` without `GG`, you'd get `44` alone, which is certainly wrong, since correct year is `44 BC` or `-43`. It's like using `h` without `a`, i.e. `17:15` and `5:15 PM` are both correct, but `5:15` alone is the wrong time of day.

Comment: that makes more sense. so the correct way would be to use `GG` as well if you are using `y`, or use `u` if you are ok with having a negative value as year.

Comment: @Sumit And that is exactly what my answer to that other question said, if you read the paragraph starting the "Conclusion:". ***Conclusion:** If you use `y` you should also use `G`. Since `G` is rarely used, the correct year symbol is `u`, not `y`, otherwise a non-positive year will show incorrectly.*

Comment: -1 due to a condescending tone. `YYYY` would appear to the layman (or someone skimming the documentation) to be a sensible way to attain the year. Thanks for your answer, but SO exists to clear up these misconceptions, even if said misconceptions are due to negligence.

Comment: -1 There is nothing wrong with the question and even though you answered it there was no need to be condescending "You might want to actually read the documentation".

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the documentation of the [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). So, `D` stands for the day of the year, while `d` is the day of the month, which is what you want.

Plus, there are several formats that are already defined. The one you want is almost like `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`.