# Confusion in java.Clock, systemDefaultZone() returning UTC time

Tags: java, scala, utc, java-time

I am trying to understand why the following `java.time.Clock` is returning UTC time instead of the local time zone (EST).

```
C:\Users\Felipe>scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_65).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import java.time._
import java.time._

scala> ZoneId.systemDefault()
res0: java.time.ZoneId = America/New_York

scala> val clock = Clock.systemDefaultZone()
clock: java.time.Clock = SystemClock[America/New_York]

scala> clock.instant
res1: java.time.Instant = 2017-07-06T16:20:04.990Z
```

The current time when I ran the above was `12:20pm` (i.e. 4h before the UTC time shown)

Comment: What does the javadoc of `Instant#toString()` say?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You are right, toString defaults to UTC. Thanks for clarifying. I was under the impression that Instant would act similarly to LocalDateTime.toString() which just shows the local time and not UTC.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229124/format-instant-to-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Instant.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toString--) method uses `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT` formatter, which in turn [parses and formats the `Instant` in UTC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT).

As `2017-07-06T16:20:04.990Z` is the same as `2017-07-06T12:20:04.990` in New York, the results you're getting are correct.

If you want the `Instant` converted to your timezone, you can do:

```
clock.instant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
```

Or you can be more specific (as the system's default timezone can be changed, even in runtime):

```
clock.instant().atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"))
```

This will result in a `ZonedDateTime`:

> 2017-07-06T12:48:22.890-04:00[America/New_York]

---

You can also convert this to a `LocalDateTime` if you want:

```
clock.instant().atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")).toLocalDateTime()
```

The result will be a `LocalDateTime`:

> 2017-07-06T12:49:47.688

---

**PS:** as [@Andreas reminded me in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44954441/confusion-in-java-clock-systemdefaultzone-returning-utc-time/44954710#comment76885189_44954710) (and I forgot to mention), the `Instant` class represents just a point in time (number of nanoseconds since `1970-01-01T00:00Z`) and has no timezone information, so any representation of it (including the `toString()` method) will be in UTC. To get the local date or time that corresponds to an `Instant`, you must provide a timezone, as shown above.

Comment: It isn't just the `toString()` method, but more the fact that `Instant` doesn't have a time zone: *The `Instant` class is designed to only represent a point in time and internally stores a value in nanoseconds from a fixed epoch of `1970-01-01Z`. As such, an Instant cannot be formatted as a date or time without providing some form of time-zone.* Hence the default format of UTC.

Comment: @Andreas Indeed! I focused the explanation on `toString()` and forgot to mention the most important part. I've added this info to the answer, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`Instant` does not have any time zone information. It is just the number of seconds/nanoseconds since epoch. `LocalDateTime` represents time in the local time zone, which can be obtained from clock using:

```
LocalDateTime.now(clock)
```

You can also convert an `Instant` to `ZonedDateTime` (which represents time along with timezone) using:

```
clock.instant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
```

Comment: If you want a `ZonedDateTime`, you should also use `ZonedDateTime.now(clock)`, not `clock.instant().atZone(...)`, so the time zone of the `ZonedDateTime` is correctly taken from the `Clock`.