# android format datetime from django

Tags: java, android, django, date, parsing

I'm connecting my django website to an android app using json and the rest framework

The json data contains datetime like this :

```
{
   date: "2018-06-05T12:42:48.545140Z"
}
```

When android receives the date, I try to format it using this code :

```
    String dt="2018-06-05T12:42:48.545140Z";
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
    String date=formatter.format(Date.parse(dt));
```

And I get the following error :

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:**

**Parse error: 2018-06-14T14:30:02.982009Z**

**at java.util.Date.parseError(Date.java:367)**

**at java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:448)**

In a django a template I can easily do this

**{{article.date|date:'d-m-Y H:i'}}**

But in android I'm a bit confused

Comment: The `parse` method of the outdated `Date` class is deprecated, don’t use it. The whole class is long outdated too, and was never well designed. Consider adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing the date format in the serializer class

```
    date = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", required=False, read_only=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [**java.time**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) API you can use :

```
String dt = "2018-06-05T12:42:48.545140Z";
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(dt); 
String newFormat = zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"));
System.out.println(newFormat);//05/06/2018 12:42
```

Note I don't use any formatter the default one of `ZonedDateTime` can parse your date.

Or as [**@Basil Bourque**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50900725/android-format-datetime-from-django/50900773?noredirect=1#comment88805015_50900773) mention it's more appropriate to parse as `Instance` instead of `ZonedDateTime` :

```
String newFormat = Instant.parse(dt)
        .atZone(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Auckland"))
        .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"));
```

### About your error

Your error comes from `Date.parse(dt)` because the default pattern of Date can't parse your date, you need to give it the correct format so it can understand how to format your date. for example :

```
String date = formatter.format(
        new SimpleDateFormat("the pattern which match your string date (dt)").format(dt)
);
```

But in any case I don't advice to use the `SimpleDateFormat` or `Date`.

The [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project back-ports to Java 6 & 7 most of the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) functionality with nearly identical API syntax. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in the [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Thanks but java.time api requires api level 26 and I didn't want to change the min sdk so I changed the date format in the serializer class

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi This can be helpful for others, in any case you can use the similar library http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/index.html which offer what java.time do

Comment: Good Answer, but parsing as a `Instant` rather than a `ZonedDateTime` would be more appropriate. The `Z` represents a mere offset-from-UTC, not a time zone.

Comment: Thank you @BasilBourque I find this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229124/format-instant-to-string about formatting and Instance, I think it is a little complicated and long piece of code to format an Instance rather than ZoneDateTime no?

Comment: @YCF_L  Yes, you are correct, `Instant` is a basic class, not intended for generating strings in custom format. For custom strings, use `OffsetDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime`. But as I said, the input seen here with a `Z` is an offset-from-UTC (an offset of zero), but is *not* a time zone. A time zone is a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset-from-UTC used by the people of a particular region, with a name in `Continent/Region` format. So you it is misleading to parse the given input as a `ZonedDateTime` though that works technically. Instead, parse as a `OffsetDateTime`.

Comment: My comments above assume the intent is to perceive the date and time-of-day in UTC. If instead the goal is to adjust into a particular time zone, then parse as a `Instant`, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Like this:  `Instant.parse( "2018-06-05T12:42:48.545140Z" ).atZone( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ).format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm") )`

Comment: Thank you @BasilBourque for the information, each time new thing from you and Ole V.V. about date and time I appreciate it