# How to convert an Epoch timestamp into an object of type java.time.Instant Accurately in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime, pojo, epoch

I have a Spring Boot JPA Application that interacts with a 3rd party API.
The response payload of the API has a key

"created_at": 1591988071

I need to parse this field into java.time.Instant so that I can do some comparisons with the value I have in the Database.
I have learned that I can use the below mentioned piece of code.

```
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1591988071);
```

Output :

```
    2020-06-12T18:54:31Z
```

**But to be honest, this output is off by a couple of hours.**

I found another approach, wherein if I use

```
    String dateAsText = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
            .format(new Date(1591988071 * 1000L));
    System.out.println(dateAsText);
```

I get the desired output but in String format.

```
    2020-06-13 00:24:31
```

**Can someone tell me how to obtain the above String output but converted into type java.time.Instant ?**

Comment: Instant or Date used for store data, they don't store any format, you can convert them in your desire  format string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format Instant to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229124/format-instant-to-string)

Comment: Accorindg to [Epoch & Unix Timestamp Conversion Tools](https://www.epochconverter.com/) 2020-06-12T18:54:31Z is perfectly accurate. The trailing `Z` means UTC (what is called GMT on the linked page).

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. They deceive you into wrong beliefs about the correct answer. Instead use `Instant`, `ZoneId`, and `ZonedDateTime`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely you're in a different timezone than UTC. The instant is giving you time in UTC. That's indicated by the `Z` at the end of your first output.

You would want to look at [atZone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-)

```java
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1591988071);
System.out.println(instant);
final ZonedDateTime losAngeles = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
System.out.println(losAngeles);
final ZonedDateTime mumbai = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC+0530"));
System.out.println(mumbai);
```

This gives you something you might expect

```
2020-06-12T18:54:31Z
2020-06-12T11:54:31-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]
2020-06-13T00:24:31+05:30[UTC+05:30]
```

Comment: Thank you for this ! Looks like i was mislead by the timezone