# Java8 java.util.Date conversion to java.time.ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-8, java-time

I am getting the following exception while trying to convert `java.util.Date` to `java.time.LocalDate`.

```
java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: 2014-08-19T05:28:16.768Z of type java.time.Instant
```

The code is as follow:

```
public static Date getNearestQuarterStartDate(Date calculateFromDate){

    int[] quaterStartMonths={1,4,7,10};     
    Date startDate=null;

    ZonedDateTime d=ZonedDateTime.from(calculateFromDate.toInstant());
    int frmDateMonth=d.getMonth().getValue();
```

Is there something wrong in the way I am using the `ZonedDateTime` class?

As per documentation, this should convert a `java.util.Date` object to `ZonedDateTime`. The date format above is standard Date?

Do I have to fallback on Joda time?

If someone could provide some suggestion, it would be great.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

To transform an `Instant` to a `ZonedDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime` offers the method [`ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant, ZoneId)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#ofInstant-java.time.Instant-java.time.ZoneId-). So

So, assuming you want a `ZonedDateTime` in the default timezone, your code should be

```
ZonedDateTime d = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(calculateFromDate.toInstant(),
                                          ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Comment: What if I want to convert it to the same timezone? Date is always UTC I believe, so I can just do ZoneId.UTC?

Comment: A Date doesn't have a timezone at all. It's just a number of millisecods elapsed since a precise moment (1970-01-01T00:00 UTC). There is no "same" timezone. If you want the ZonedDateTime to be in the UTC timezone, you must pass ZoneOffset.UTC.

Comment: @DidierA. A `Date` is similar to an `Instant`, which are both UNIX timestamps.  Also, it is common practice to say that UNIX timestamps are UTC time zone.

Answer (score 44):

To obtain a ZonedDateTime from a Date you can use:

```
calculateFromDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
```

You can then call the `toLocalDate` method if you need a LocalDate. See also: [Convert java.util.Date to java.time.LocalDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242110/convert-java-util-date-to-java-time-localdate/21242111)

Comment: The above solution also works out for me and the conversion to LocalDate was very useful. One question, from design perspective ZonedDateTime.from() should behave as expected as long as it is provided with an java.time.Instant. In this case, it is not as expected. Is this some kind of inconsistency?

Comment: ZonedDateTime.from() requires a ZoneId, but Instant does not have one. As such, ZonedDateTime.from(instant) throws an exception.

Answer (score 17):

The [Answer by assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25377049/642706) and the [Answer by JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25376733/642706) are both correct:

1. Call the new conversion method added to the legacy class, [`java.util.Date::toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html#toInstant()).
2. Call [`Instant::atZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#atZone(java.time.ZoneId)), passing a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html), resulting in a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

[image]

But your code example is aimed at quarters. For that, read on.

## Quarters

No need to roll-your-own handling of quarters. Use a class already written and tested.

### `org.threeten.extra.YearQuarter`

The *java.time* classes are extended by the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. Among the many handy classes provided in that library you will find [`Quarter`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Quarter.html) and [`YearQuarter`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html).

First get your [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZonedId z = ZoneID.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant().atZone( z ) ;
```

Determine the year-quarter for that particular date.

```
YearQuarter yq = YearQuarter.from( zdt ) ;
```

Next we need the start date of that quarter.

```
LocalDate quarterStart = yq.atDay( 1 ) ;
```

While I do not necessarily recommend doing so, you could use a single line of code rather than implement a method.

```
LocalDate quarterStart =                    // Represent a date-only, without time-of-day and without time zone.
    YearQuarter                             // Represent a specific quarter using the ThreeTen-Extra class `org.threeten.extra.YearQuarter`. 
    .from(                                  // Given a moment, determine its year-quarter.
        myJavaUtilDate                      // Terrible legacy class `java.util.Date` represents a moment in UTC as a count of milliseconds since the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. Avoid using this class if at all possible.
        .toInstant()                        // New method on old class to convert from legacy to modern. `Instant` represents a moment in UTC as a count of nanoseconds since the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. 
        .atZone(                            // Adjust from UTC to the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone). Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
            ZoneID.of( "Africa/Tunis" )     // Specify a time zone using proper `Continent/Region` format. Never use 2-4 letter pseudo-zone such as `PST` or `EST` or `IST`. 
        )                                   // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
    )                                       // Returns a `YearQuarter` object.
    .atDay( 1 )                             // Returns a `LocalDate` object, the first day of the quarter. 
;
```

By the way, if you can phase out your use of `java.util.Date` altogether, do so. It is a *terrible* class, along with its siblings such as `Calendar`. Use `Date` only where you must, when you are interfacing with old code not yet updated to *java.time*.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The answer didn't work for me on Java 10 storing util.Date in UTC.

Date.toInstant() seems to convert the EpochMillis into the local time zone of the server.

ZDT.ofInstant(instant, zoneId) and instant.atZone(zoneId) seem to just tag on a TZ on the instant, but it's already messed up with.

I couldn't find a way to prevent Date.toInstant() from messing with the UTC time with the system time zone.

The only way I found to work around this was to go through the sql.Timestamp class:

```
new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()).toLocalDateTime()
                                      .atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))
                                      .withZoneSameInstant(desiredTZ)
```

Comment: No, there is no conversion with `Date::toInstant`. Both a `java.util.Date` and a `java.time.Instant` are in UTC, by definition, always in UTC. `Date` represents a count of milliseconds since the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, while `Instant` is also a count since the same epoch but in finer resolution of nanoseconds.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is exactly the *wrong* class to be using here. That class purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. As such, it is incapable of representing a moment, as noted in its class JavaDoc. Converting to a `LocalDateTime` is discarding valuable information with nothing gained. This Answer is misleading and incorrect. See the [correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25377049/642706) by assylias. All you need to get a `ZonedDateTime` from a `Date` is: `myJavaUtilDate.toInstant().atZone( desiredZoneIdGoesHere )`.

Comment: Basil, I 100% agree with your expectation but this is sadly not how we witnessed Java 10 behave with a UTC Date in a PST JVM. We're only using the LocalDateTime here as an intermediate var to not get the UTC time messed up before we tag a TZ on it.

Comment: There is no reason to ever use `java.sql.Timestamp` again, now replaced by `java.sql.OffsetDateTime` -- as of JDBC 4.2 we can directly exchange some *java.time* types with the database.

Comment: I suggest that instead of posting this Answer, you post your own Question delineating the problem you encountered, along with example code. We should be able to sort that out for you.

Comment: Regarding your “PST JVM”… You can, and should, write code with *java.time* that never relies on your JVM’s current default time zone. Instead, you should generally work in UTC (`java.time.Instant`, or `OffsetDateTime` set to `ZoneOffset.UTC`), and always pass the optional `ZoneId`/`ZoneOffset`. Another issue, never use the pseudo-time zone “PST”. Proper time zone names are in `Continent/Region` format, such as `America/Los_Angeles`. See [Wikipedia for list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Comment: Basil, the question was about converting a util.Date so I was answering that. java.time types are better I agree but that was not the question again. I think the issue we experienced with util.Date.toInstant() is relevant and will be helpful to others who run into it. If you can work exclusively with java.time types than good for you. No need to troll here.

Comment: No trolling here. In my suggestion for you to post a Question, I was sincerely offering to work out a solution to the problem you encountered. I suspect the problem and solution would be interesting and valuable to others.