# How to convert Date to ZonedDateTime?

Tags: java

I've got various `java.util.Date` objects with values of this format: `2014-01-21 10:28:57.122Z`. I would like to convert them all to `ZonedDateTime` objects.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25376242/java8-java-util-date-conversion-to-java-time-zoneddatetime) SO question, and [`ZonedDateTime`'s `ofInstant()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#ofInstant-java.time.Instant-java.time.ZoneId-), one way is like so:

```
ZonedDateTime z = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(dateObject.toInstant(), ZoneId);
```

The problem is, how do I figure out what to use for the `ZoneId` parameter? I can't use my system time (`ZoneId.systemDefault()`) because my `Date` objects all have different timezones.

Comment: If they end in `Z` they are UTC by definition. Can you [edit] to show us the code where you create / parse for these objects?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `java.util.Date` object does **not** have a time zone. Dates are always stored internally in UTC.

When you parse a text string into a `Date` object, the parser applies a time zone, either as given in the text, as a parameter to the parser, or by default.

When you display a `Date` object, the formatter will generate the text as requested, in the time zone requested, whether the time zone is displayed or not.

So, without time zone information in the `Date` object, **you** must specify the time zone you want when converting to `ZonedDateTime`.

Better yet, parse the text directly to a ZonedDateTime, so **it** can remember the original time zone from the text.

Comment: Very Good Explanation @Andreas