# Convert DStream[java.util.Date] to DStream[String]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, twitter4j, spark-streaming

I'm trying to union two Dstreams:

```
val statuses = tweets.map(status => status.getText())
    val users = tweets.map(status => status.getUser())
    val Dates = tweets.map(status => status.getCreatedAt())
    (statuses. union(Dates)).print
```

But I'm getting an error that there is a mismatch in types:

```
Found: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[java.util.Date]

Required: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[String]
```

How can I do the conversion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert java.util.Date to String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683728/convert-java-util-date-to-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
val Dates = tweets.map(status => status.getCreatedAt.toString)
```

or if you want specific format

```
val format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
val Dates = tweets.map(status => format.format(status.getCreatedAt))
```