# Scala Slick 3.0 implicit mapping between java8 OffsetDateTime and Timestamp

Tags: java, scala, datetime, slick

First is if I want to map datetime with timezone to Slick, which class should I use `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime`? As for Joda, we can only use `DateTime`.

How I can write some implicit to convert between java8 `ZonedDateTime` and Sql `Timestamp` for Slick table mapping?

It seems quite straightforward to use joda `DateTime` to include timezone information. However once switch to Java8, not quite sure whether I should use `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime`, as http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html suggests to use OffsetDateTime.

For my current code, I just use Java8 `LocalDateTime` and I write following implicit to map between slick.

```
implicit val JavaLocalDateTimeMapper = MappedColumnType.base[LocalDateTime, Timestamp](
    l => Timestamp.valueOf(l),
    t => t.toLocalDateTime
  )
```

Not quite sure I can write similar using either `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Short Answer

As of Slick 3.1, the short answer is to use [OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), but you'll need to map it to a `String` column, not a `Timestamp` for it to work with any database.

That is, you'll need a `MappedColumnType.base[OffsetDateTime, String]`.  You can use `toString` and `OffsetDateTime.parse` for the string conversion:

```
scala> import java.time._
import java.time._

scala> val paris = ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris")
paris: java.time.ZoneId = Europe/Paris

scala> OffsetDateTime.now(paris)
res0: java.time.OffsetDateTime = 2016-01-05T20:38:46.473+01:00

scala> OffsetDateTime.parse(res0.toString)
res2: java.time.OffsetDateTime = 2016-01-05T20:38:46.473+01:00
```

## Longer Answer

The difference between [OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) and [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) is covered by the answer to [What's the difference between java 8 ZonedDateTime and OffsetDateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30234594/whats-the-difference-between-java-8-zoneddatetime-and-offsetdatetime), so I won't repeat it here.

However, you'll want to read that to decide if the short answer matches up to your situation.

If you use Postgres, [there's support for java.time](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg/issues/248) via the [slick-pg](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg) project. I've not had the chance to use it myself, but clearly worth investigating if that's the database you're using. See e.g., [the test suite](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg/blob/master/addons/date2/src/test/scala/com/github/tminglei/slickpg/PgDate2SupportSuite.scala) for the "date2" add-on.

## The Better Answer (or, Future Answer!)

The wonderful news is that there's an active pull request to add support for the java.time data types in Slick.  You can monitor the progress [on the ticket](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1026), which is currently scheduled for Slick 3.2.

Comment: Thanks Richard, the last answer is what I expected :-)

Comment: Built-in support for java.time mappings in Slick landed in Slick 3.3.0 (i.e., the last answer: "Future Answer")

Answer (score 0):

There was a fork which I don't believe was ever released, but it did have Java8 time support:

https://github.com/xavier-fernandez/slick

It's quite stable, and I've been using it with HSQLDB in prod. And the related specification/pull request:

https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/1349

If you're looking for code generation, it's not too difficult, using the above-mentioned fork, this post describes how to do it:

https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/1349#issuecomment-245566307