# TimePicker to setText, simple bug

Tags: android

After picking a time from a `TimePicker` I am displaying that using `setText()` , however , so far everything works well, however the problem is , if I choose `05:09` , I only get displayed `5:9 PM` in `TextView`. I miss the preceding zeros. But I require that

Here is the Code I use :

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker,int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) 
{
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selectedHour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute);

    int c_hour,c_min;
    String format;
    c_hour=selectedHour;
    c_min=selectedMinute;

    if (c_hour == 0) {
          c_hour += 12;
          format = "AM";
    } 
    else if (c_hour == 12) {
          format = "PM";
    } 
    else if (c_hour > 12) {
          c_hour -= 12;
          format = "PM";
    } 
    else {
         format = "AM";
    }

TextView dimple = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeText);
dimple.setText(new StringBuilder().
            append(c_hour).append(" : ").append(c_min).append(" ").append(format));
```

What is the quick way to fix it ?

Comment: You are not doing any calculations on the `c_min` `int` variable, so you can make it string. or you could convert it to string at the end and then if the length is 1 add a preceeding 0

Comment: This is because you use `variables` as `int` just make it `string` and when accessing it convert it to the `int` using parsing of the string method.

Comment: see if you get help at http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-time-picker-example/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the time, by prefixing zeros.

> String formatTime=`String.format("%02d : %02d", hour, minute)`;

**or**

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        String formatTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a").format(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: clean line of code , +1 to that , But how to add AM and PM to that  ? So I can call the formatTime from setText

Comment: @oblivion, you could use the following code: `String formatTime = String.format("%02d : %02d %s", hour, minute, format);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use SimpleDateFormat for constructing time string as mentioned here:

[Convert java.util.Date to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683728/convert-java-util-date-to-string)

In your case you can use "HH:mm a" as the format.

So your sample code should look like:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selectedHour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute);

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");

Date dateValue = calendar.getTime();
String requiredTime = dateFormat.format(dateValue);
TextView dimple = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeText);
dimple.setText(requiredTime);
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String str_hour = c_hour<10 ? "0"+String.valueOf(c_hour):String.valueOf(c_hour);   

String str_min = c_min<10 ? "0"+String.valueOf(c_min):String.valueOf(c_min);
```