# Converting date to a text field

Tags: java, database, date, time, clock

I have this date shown on my GUI. I want my database to store this date value. How to do it? The image is that of the date shown. How to display this date to a text field and to my database? (sql server)

[Link of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89Si7.jpg)

```
    public class ClockPane extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JLabel clock;

    public ClockPane() {
        setBounds(235, 25, 580, 43);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setBackground(Color .white);
        clock = new JLabel();
        clock.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        clock.setFont(UIManager.getFont("Label.font").deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 15f)); //15f = size of timer
        tickTock();
        add(clock);

        Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tickTock();
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.setCoalesce(true);
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void tickTock() {
        clock.setText(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()));
    }
```

Comment: Search Stack Overflow before posting. This has been addressed hundreds, if not thousands, of times already.

Comment: And a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5683728/642706