# How to set Date and Time in the Absolute Path

Tags: java

I want to write a file in the `Absolute Path` with date and Time. for example C:\Users\PC\programme\NewDATA_15/06/2016 00.35.57.txt. `NewDATA_15/06/2016 00.35.57.txt` is a file name.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question.
Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community

Comment: If this is for Windows, "/" is illegal. And: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5683761/669576

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `\\` and `/` use `File.separator` for all File operations.

and for the date part look at the link that Johnny Mopp has already commented: [Convert java.util.Date to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683728/convert-java-util-date-to-string/5683761#5683761)

Comment: I am just guessing that this is your problem cause your question has no Information, hope that helps