# java.util.date to String using DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, jodatime, datetimeformatter

How can I convert a `java.util.Date` to `String` using

```
 DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
```

The Date object which I get is passed

```
DateTime now = new DateTime(date);
```

Comment: Please show your complete code

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683728/convert-java-util-date-to-string

Comment: @PeterKuebler I am trying to use DateTimeFormatter

Comment: Why not use `SimpleDateFormat`?

Comment: `new DateTime(date).toString(dateTimeFormatter)`

Comment: @CorkKochi If you are on Java 8 you should consider using the new java time api instead of the legacy Date api or joda time.

Comment: not clear for me, is DateTimeFormatter  comming from  java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter; or org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter???

Comment: I assume it's Joda, but I don't know why it's tagged `java-8`.

Comment: @shmosel Any possibilities to do in java8

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Joda, Java and Java 8 have separate date libraries, with their own formatting and parsing mechanisms, all of which are well documented on this site and elsewhere. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @shmosel can you tell how it can be done in java8, I searched but I couldnt find

Comment: FYI: The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 41):

If you are using Java 8, you should not use `java.util.Date` in the first place (unless you receive the `Date` object from a library that you have no control over).

In any case, you can convert a `Date` to a `java.time.Instant` using:

```
Date date = ...;
Instant instant = date.toInstant();
```

Since you are only interested in the date and time, without timezone information (I assume everything is UTC), you can convert that instant to a `LocalDateTime` object:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();
```

Finally you can print it with:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(ldt.format(fmt));
```

Or use the predefined formatter, [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME).

```
System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));
```

Note that if you don't provide a formatter, calling [`ldt.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toString--) gives output in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format (including milliseconds) - that may be acceptable for you.

Comment: The service I am using is returning a java.util.Date object

Comment: @CorkKochi If you *must* use a `java.util.Date` object, convert as shown in this Answer. See new conversion methods added to the old classes, such as [`Date.from( Instant )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from-java.time.Instant-) and [`Date::toInstant()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toInstant--).

Answer (score 8):

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
Instant instant = date.toInstant();

LocalDateTime ldt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();

DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(ldt.format(fmt));
```

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing and simplifying @assylias and @Adrian Faur:

```
 dateTimeFormatter.format(date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
```

No need to convert it to `LocalDateTime`, format accept `TemporalAccessor`

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(date);
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
dt.toString(dtf)
```

Comment: `dt.toString(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT)`

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTimeFormatterOBJECT=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("DD/MMM/YYYY HH//MM/SS");

String MyDateAndTime= LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatterOBJECT);
```

Comment: You can use above code to get simple date in your own format by specifying the format in first line of code and you can also use any plus or minus date function in 2nd line of code ;

Comment: To add clarifications to your answer, please edit your answer instead of using comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the joda time formatter class:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
# conflict with import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
            .withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);

    System.out.println(DateTime.now().toString(formatter));
```

Comment: You can also use `withZoneUTC()` instead of `withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)` which results in an unnecessary import of `DateTimeZone` class.

Answer (score -1):

since I asume you are using joda API: 
ergo, DateTimeFormatter  is comming from **org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter**:

```
 String dateTime = "02-13-2017 18:20:30";
// Format for input
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
// Parsing the date
DateTime jodatime = dtf.parseDateTime(dateTime);

System.out.println(jodatime );
```

Comment: @CorkKochi I hope you're not actually calling `new DateTime(new Date())`.

Comment: @shmosel I posted the answer