# @DateTimeFormat, convert string to Date (java)

Tags: java, spring, date

I'm currently with this problem. I have a `Date.toString()`. On one side, I want to send this to some other side as a `Date`. How to do this?

Here is my code:

```
public void createEmployee(Employee emp) throws HelicarrierException {
    log.debug(LOG_PREFIX + "[SERVICE]-[CREATE-LOG-GOAL] - [GOAL] - [{}]", emp);
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("nameEmployee", emp.getName());
    map.put("admissionalDate", emp.getAdmissionDate().toString());

    RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();

    String url = "http://" + properties.getSktServerEndpoint()
            + ":" + properties.getSktServerPort()
            + properties.getModelEmployee()
            + properties.getCreateEmployee();

    log.debug(LOG_PREFIX + "-[URL]-[{}]", url);
    log.debug(LOG_PREFIX + "-[PARAMETERS]-[{}]", map);

    try {
        rt.postForObject(url, emp, Employee.class, map);
    }
```

Note that `emp.getAdmissionDate().toString() = Mon Oct 15 00:00:00 BRT 2018`

And I'm trying to map this parameter on the other side like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "/create", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<GenericResponse> create(@RequestParam(value = "nameEmployee") String nameEmployee, @RequestParam(name = "admissionalDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy)) Date admissionalDate)
```

But I always get, Bad Request error. I think the `Date` mapping is wrong, but I don't know how to do it right. Anyone know, how to map properly, this string to date?

Comment: Why do you use `Date.toString()` in first place? why to do not use standard format for communications - ISO-8601?

Comment: Because the map<String, String> obligates me. I have to make Date.toString() to be able to put the date inside the map

Comment: Not a correct answer: ISO-8601 is a String format for Date/Time which is more suitable to pass Date/Time as String

Comment: Maybe you can make the second type parameter of the hashmap a LocalDateTime type instead of a String type?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this Issue you have a couple of options:

## 1 Use Locale or a DateTime-Formatter

Use a DateTime-Formatter to send the String-Representation of the date and parse it APPROPRIATE on the other side to a date.

A very common Format for Timestamps is as already mentioned ISO-8601

## 2 Send another data-Type

you could send directly Date(s) or DateTimes

---

In your case it seems like the `@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy)` is incorrect.

Your output string is formatted as `Mon Oct 15 00:00:00 BRT 2018`.
The appropriate format for this String on the other side would be `EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy`.

For more information take a look inside the [DateTimeFormatter-Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Or take a look at [another posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42210257/java-util-date-to-string-using-datetimeformatter).

Comment: Thx duffy, for your answer. But i've tried to map the date like you said, and didn't work, i've kept receiving bad request error.

Comment: does it work, if you remove the second parameter? There might be another error in your endpoint, so you could remove the date-parameter and try again - if the error is still there, the date-parameter is not the problem