# Get Timestamp in specific format

Tags: java, date, jdbc, timestamp

I have a timestamp saved in Azure SQL Database in the format of 2004-09-23 10:52:00. When I fetch the value, I am using sqlrowset where I am using `getString("last_updated_user")` and getting output like this "2004-09-23 10:52:00.0". When I tried using `getTimeStamp("last_updated_user")`, I am getting in microseconds. Can someone help me on formatting it to "2004-09-23 10:52:00" based on some in-built functions like .format or something and not by just removing the decimal by replace or substring?

Comment: Java a look at the `java.time` API which should provide all you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.util.date to String using DateTimeFormatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42210257/java-util-date-to-string-using-datetimeformatter)

Comment: Or perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/change-date-format-in-a-java-string

Comment: What is the actual data type of your column `last_updated_user`?

Comment: Don’t get your date and time as a string from your database. Get a `LocalDateTime`. See [Arvind Kumar Avinash’ good answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/5772882).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String d = "2004-09-23 10:52:00.0";
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M-d H:m:s.S", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(d, dtfInput);

        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String str = ldt.format(dtfOutput);
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2004-09-23 10:52:00
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/hfe45x)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from [Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

### JDBC 4.2 and java.time

I am guessing a bit here since I don’t know Azure SQL database. What you are reporting sounds like you are having an SQL `timestamp` or equivalent in your database. Assuming that your JDBC driver is JDBC 4.2 compliant get a `LocalDateTime` (not a string) from your database:

```
    LocalDateTime lastUpdatedUser
            = sqlrowset.getObject("last_updated_user", LocalDateTime.class);
```

I have further assumed that `sqlrowset` is a `javax.sql.RowSet`. To format into your desired string use a formatter like this one:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Now we may do:

```
    System.out.println("LocalDateTime retrieved: " + lastUpdatedUser);
    String formatted = lastUpdatedUser.format(FORMATTER);
    System.out.println("Formatted:               " + formatted);
```

Example output:

> ```
> LocalDateTime retrieved: 2004-09-23T10:52
> Formatted:               2004-09-23 10:52:00
> ```