# Date stored in different format

Tags: date, spring-boot, jackson2

I have this date `"2018-05-30T16:19:58.016Z"` coming from my Angular app.
In Spring, the field `date` is as follows :

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
private Date date;
```

The date is well stored, but with this format `YYYY-MM-dd`.
[image]

Is there anything that I'm missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql `date` type can't hold data with timestamp. It has to be `datetime` in order to contain date time with timestamp data.

Comment: That answer is indeed very useful! I'll just change the type to `datetime` and see what I have.

Comment: I just changed the annotation from `DATE` to `TERMPORAL` and all is fine now.

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to specify the date format going out to the storage, as `@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")` only specifies the date format for parsing the date into the Date object. Even if your Date has all of the seconds and timezone information, the default Date `toString()` is still

> Formats a date in the date escape format yyyy-mm-dd.

according to the Java 8 docs. So if you are using that, it would most likely drop all that extra information on conversion.

You can look at this [Convert java.util.Date to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683728/convert-java-util-date-to-string) for information on how to get a Date to a formatted String.

Comment: So you suggest to change the date format in the setter?

Comment: @androniennn how are you storing your Date in your database? maybe edit your question to add that

Comment: I save the object, and the date field is stored. I have no problem with that. I think that I will try to make as you suggested: a small transformation in date before setting it.

Comment: @androniennn when you say `I save the object, and the date field is stored` that might be the issue. If your "save the object" code uses toString() to save the date object, then, according to the javadocs, it would be saving it as yyyy-mm-dd. Without knowing what you are using to save the object, I can't say for sure.