# Sorting Date by taking input (Date) as String

Tags: java, string, date

I have a problem where i need to sort the record according to the `date of birth.`
I tried to use `String.comapreTo` but it is only sorting by the days. not by year or month.

```
class Sortbydob {
    void sortString(String[] First_name, String[] Last_name, String[] Dob, int[] Percent) {
        String tempvaule;
        int temphold;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < 3; j++) {
                if (Dob[i].compareTo(Dob[j]) > 0)
{
//Swapping
}


    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            Sortbyname obj = new Sortbyname();
            String[] First_name = new String[3];
            String[] Last_name = new String[3];
            String[] Dob = new String[3];
            int[] Percent = new int[3];
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter the First Name : ");
                First_name[i] = in.next();
                System.out.println("Enter the First Name : ");
                Last_name[i] = in.next();
                System.out.println("Enter the Dob in DD/MM/YYYY Format : ");
                Dob[i] = in.next();
                System.out.println("Enter the Percentage : ");
                Percent[i] = in.nextInt();

            }
```

so i need to take the input `First and last name, DOB ,percentage` and sort it based on Date of birth. Challenge is **i cannot use any type of Array list or linked array or hash map or table or tree etc.** 
Can Anyone help me to sort with basic logic?

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names are always written in camelCase. For example, `Last_name` should then be `lastName`.

Comment: If you date format is dd/mm/yyyy, sorting in alphabetical order won't be the same as chronological order... It would be simpler to store the dates as ... dates, using the `LocalDate` class for example.

Comment: Besides, this structure is the opposite of the object-oriented paradigm. Instead of a method accepting four separate arrays, a class `Person` or something should be created with the properties `firstname`, `lastname`, `dob` and `percent`, and the method should accept an array, or even better, a `List` containing the `Person` objects to be sorted.

Comment: @MCEmperor yes. but do you know how do we do in code? can you help me?

Comment: @assylias Can you help me with the code? How to take input and sort by DOB

Comment: @MCEmperor points out one design problem (more here: [Anti-pattern: parallel collections](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/)). Another one is storing dates as strings. Your sorting problem comes from this. Store your dates as `LocalDate` objects and use their natural ordering for sorting, and everything will go smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the date from a `String` to a `Date`

You would need to do something like:

```
Date dobDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").parse(Dob[i]);
```

Once you have the dates converted to `Date` objects, you can sort them using the built in compare methods: `after()` `before()` `equals()`

Check out [How to compare dates in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/how-to-compare-dates-in-java) to see details

Comment: But it is showing along with time.How to Avoid it?

Comment: What do you mean "it is showing along with time"? You mean when you print the date? For displaying the date, you can parse it again, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683728/convert-java-util-date-to-string this question answers that.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Also I don’t think your code sorts months before days of the month.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it quick, you could use a recursive quicksort implementation that sorts by the `String` part representing years first, then months, then days. In the following example, you have to provide the positions of the year (`yyyy`), the month (`MM`) and the day (`dd`) as well as the character that delimits them in the date format pattern:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] birthdays = { 
            "10/05/1990",
            "10/05/2001",
            "10/05/2006",
            "10/05/1960",
            "10/05/2033" 
    };

    // print the unsorted array (build up one-line representation first)
    StringBuilder unsortedBirthdaysBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < birthdays.length; i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            unsortedBirthdaysBuilder.append(", ");
        }
        unsortedBirthdaysBuilder.append(birthdays[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("unsorted:\t" + unsortedBirthdaysBuilder.toString());

    // do the sorting
    quickBirthdaySort(birthdays, "/", 2, 1, 0);

    // print the sorted array (build up one-line representation first)
    StringBuilder sortedBirthdaysBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < birthdays.length; i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            sortedBirthdaysBuilder.append(", ");
        }
        sortedBirthdaysBuilder.append(birthdays[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("sorted:\t\t" + sortedBirthdaysBuilder.toString());
}

public static void quickBirthdaySort(String[] birthdays, String delimiter,
        int yearPatternPosition, int monthPatternPosition,
        int dayPatternPosition) {
    String temp;
    int a, b, c, d, e, f;

    for (int i = 0; i < birthdays.length - 1; i++) {
        // sort by years first
        a = Integer.valueOf(birthdays[i].split(delimiter)[yearPatternPosition]);
        b = Integer.valueOf(birthdays[i + 1].split(delimiter)[yearPatternPosition]);
        if (a > b) {
            temp = birthdays[i];
            birthdays[i] = birthdays[i + 1];
            birthdays[i + 1] = temp;
            quickBirthdaySort(birthdays, delimiter, yearPatternPosition,
                    monthPatternPosition, dayPatternPosition);
        } else if (a == b) {
            // then sort by months
            c = Integer.valueOf(birthdays[i].split(delimiter)[monthPatternPosition]);
            d = Integer.valueOf(birthdays[i + 1].split(delimiter)[monthPatternPosition]);
            if (c > d) {
                temp = birthdays[i];
                birthdays[i] = birthdays[i + 1];
                birthdays[i + 1] = temp;
                quickBirthdaySort(birthdays, delimiter, yearPatternPosition,
                        monthPatternPosition, dayPatternPosition);
            } else if (c == d) {
                // finally sort by days
                e = Integer.valueOf(birthdays[i].split("-")[dayPatternPosition]);
                f = Integer.valueOf(birthdays[i + 1].split("-")[dayPatternPosition]);
                if (e > f) {
                    temp = birthdays[i];
                    birthdays[i] = birthdays[i + 1];
                    birthdays[i + 1] = temp;
                    quickBirthdaySort(birthdays, delimiter, yearPatternPosition,
                            monthPatternPosition, dayPatternPosition);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this code is the following:

```
unsorted:   10/05/1990, 10/05/2001, 10/05/2006, 10/05/1960, 10/05/2033
sorted:     10/05/1960, 10/05/1990, 10/05/2001, 10/05/2006, 10/05/2033
```

The positions of the date parts are given as array indexes, virtually as if the `String` was already split by the delimiter. For this example, I have taken the positions from your pattern (`dd/MM/yyyy`).

> Please note that I haven't compared its runtime to any alternative, that's your part, especially because you didn't give any comparison data for the runtime.
>   Also note that this just sorts `String`s. You have to use this for sorting your objects.