# Unexpected side effects when parsing dates in Android

Tags: android, android-date

In various Android projects, I use the following static function to parse dates such as `1900-12-31`. Of course, this function should be deterministic - but it turns out it is not. Why?

Normally, it parses the date `2010-10-30`, for example, to the correct `Date` instance holding that value. But I have noticed that when I have an `IntentService` running at the same time and parsing some dates, this function parses the same date as above to `1983-01-20`, which is one of the dates parsed in the `IntentService`. How can this happen?

```
public static Date dateFromString(String dateStr) {
    SimpleDateFormat mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
    SimpleDateFormat mDateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", Locale.getDefault());
    Date dateOut = null;
    try {
        if (dateStr != null) {
            if (dateStr.length() == 7) {
                if (dateStr.startsWith("--")) {
                    dateStr = "0000"+dateStr.substring(1);
                }
            }
            else if (dateStr.length() == 6) {
                if (dateStr.startsWith("-")) {
                    dateStr = "0000"+dateStr;
                }
            }
            else if (dateStr.length() == 5) {
                dateStr = "0000-"+dateStr;
            }
            else if (dateStr.matches("[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{4}")) {
                dateStr = dateStr.substring(6, 10)+"-"+dateStr.substring(3, 5)+"-"+dateStr.substring(0, 2);
            }
            else if (dateStr.matches("[0-9]{2}\\/[0-9]{2}\\/[0-9]{4}")) {
                dateStr = dateStr.substring(6, 10)+"-"+dateStr.substring(3, 5)+"-"+dateStr.substring(0, 2);
            }
            else if (dateStr.matches("[0-9]{8}")) {
                dateStr = dateStr.substring(0, 4)+"-"+dateStr.substring(4, 6)+"-"+dateStr.substring(6, 8);
            }
            if (dateStr.length() >= 20) {
                String dateTimeStr = dateStr.trim();
                if (dateTimeStr.endsWith("Z")) {
                    dateTimeStr = dateStr.substring(0, dateTimeStr.length()-1)+"+0000";
                }
                if (dateStr.charAt(10) == ' ') {
                    dateTimeStr = dateStr.substring(0, 10)+"T"+dateStr.substring(11);
                }
                try {
                    dateOut = mDateTimeFormat.parse(dateTimeStr);
                }
                catch (Exception e2) {
                    dateOut = mDateFormat.parse(dateStr);
                }
            }
            else {
                dateOut = mDateFormat.parse(dateStr);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        dateOut = null;
    }
    return dateOut;
}
```

**Edit:** I do the parsing in my `Activity`'s `onCreate()` where I start an `AsyncTask` that does the job. In the `Activity`'s `onStop()`, a background service is started which does the same job. When I close the app (onStop()) and quickly restart it (onCreate()), both seem to be running simultaneously and the error occurrs.

Comment: Just as an experiment, what happens if you make `dateFromString` synchronized?

Comment: Firstly, why is the method `static` and secondly which class is it in?

Comment: @DiegoBasch Thanks, I will try! But actually, `synchronized` should by no means be necessary, as it only prevents interference on objects - which are not used here (static).

Comment: @Squonk Actually, it used to be non-static before. But as it does not operate on any objects, I made it static. The problem also occurred for the non-static method. It is located in `MyApp.java` which extends `Application`.

Comment: @MarcoW. : I think the answer from Dheeraj V.S. probably explains it. The fact `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe is most likely to be the cause of the problem.

Comment: I suspect the code you have shown is not the source of the problem.  somewhere you are taking the results of this function and storing it in a data structure.  That is where your race condition is most likely  occurring.  Take a look at the code of where you store the results -- is that data structure synchronized?

Comment: @iagreen I have checked that the problem is not caused by external data structures or methods, it was just in this method where I logged all the input and output. As you can see, the thread-safety of `SimpleDateFormat` was the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation of [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) says:

> SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe. Users should create a separate
>   instance for each thread.

There you go. Just create the `SimpleDateFormat` object separately in each thread and pass it to the method.

Comment: He does create a separate instance in each thread, in fact he creates two new instances in every call.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't expect the `parse()` method to have side effects and change some of the class's fields - but in fact the `parse()` method (which is inherited from the `Date` class) writes to `Date`'s field `calendar`. Thus, it's logical that concurrent use of `parse()` causes problems.