# Date parsing magic

Tags: java, parsing, date, simpledateformat

Here is my code:

```
private static final DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
....
private static Date parseIfModifiedSince(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String lastModifiedHeader = "";
    try {
        lastModifiedHeader = request.getHeader(IF_MODIFIED_SINCE);
        return !StringUtils.isEmpty(lastModifiedHeader) ? DATE_FORMAT.parse(lastModifiedHeader) : null;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.warn("Error while parsing If-Modified-Since date: \"" + lastModifiedHeader+"\"", ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Sometimes I see an exception:

```
WARN ru.planeta.web.res.ResourcesController 2013-03-29 20:16:58,635: Error while parsing If-Modified-Since date: "Fri, 29 Mar 2013 16:16:28 GMT"
java.lang.NumberFormatException: multiple points
```

I can't find any problem in code. What's wrong with me?

Comment: Not sure, but don't you need a `dd` to specify a 2-digit date?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021151/java-dateformat-is-not-threadsafe-what-does-this-leads-to - may be this can help. Try makeing your DF ThreadLocal.

Comment: [SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe](http://www.palantir.com/2007/07/simpledateformat-is-not-thread-safe/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring the `SimpleDateFormat` as a class-level variable exposes you to that problem since it isn't thread-safe. I would recommend you to create a new `SimpleDateFormat` object each time you need one and only assign it to a local variable within the method.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sarath mentioned, `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe.  An alternate solution would be to use `FastDateFormat`, which is thread safe.