# How to convert an Instant to a date format?

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-8, simpledateformat

I can convert a [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) to a [`java.time.Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) (Java 8 and later) this way:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
Date startTime = cal.getTime();
Instant i = startTime.toInstant();
```

Can anybody let me know about the convert that instant to date with a specific date & time format? i.e 2015-06-02 8:30:00

I have gone through api but could not find a satisfactory answer.

Comment: do you want a `String` output with `yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s`?

Comment: Is there any particular reason to get the instant from Calendar? and not using the LocalDate or other java.time classes? You are using calendar you can do the Calendar.getTime() which will return the Date instance. Which you can later convert to any format

Comment: actually from client i get only instant object.. now i need to store the date and time of instant in database.

Answer (score 366):

If you want to convert an `Instant` to a `Date`:

```
Date myDate = Date.from(instant);
```

And then you can use `SimpleDateFormat` for the formatting part of your question:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String formattedDate = formatter.format(myDate);
```

Comment: Use `DateTimeFormatter` instead of `SimpleDateFormat` as it is not thread safe. I have faced some issue in past because of this. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021151/java-dateformat-is-not-threadsafe-what-does-this-leads-to)

Comment: Date and SimpleDateFormat are old pre java8 implementation, It should be avoided. The not  thread safe thing is one of the problem, the non management of time zone and ofset is another one. But if you really want to face a time zone bug then stick to old Date implementation.

Comment: Whenever saying "such and such should be avoided", try to provide the alternatives.

Comment: Can we force the Date.From to be UTC? 
Thanks

Comment: Date.from(instant) will give java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ArithmeticException: long overflow in case instant is Instant.MAX

Answer (score 37):

An Instant is what it says: a specific instant in time - it does not have the notion of date and time (the time in New York and Tokyo is not the same at a given instant).

To print it as a date/time, you first need to decide which timezone to use. For example:

```
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.ofInstant(i, ZoneOffset.UTC));
```

This will print the date/time in iso format: `2015-06-02T10:15:02.325`

If you want a different format you can use a formatter:

```
LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(i, ZoneOffset.UTC);
String formatted = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(datetime);
System.out.println(formatted);
```

Answer (score 3):

try **Parsing and Formatting**

Take an example
**Parsing**

```
String input = ...;
try {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter =
                      DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d yyyy");
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(input, formatter);
    System.out.printf("%s%n", date);
}
catch (DateTimeParseException exc) {
    System.out.printf("%s is not parsable!%n", input);
    throw exc;      // Rethrow the exception.
}
```

**Formatting**

```
ZoneId leavingZone = ...;
ZonedDateTime departure = ...;

try {
    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d yyyy  hh:mm a");
    String out = departure.format(format);
    System.out.printf("LEAVING:  %s (%s)%n", out, leavingZone);
}
catch (DateTimeException exc) {
    System.out.printf("%s can't be formatted!%n", departure);
    throw exc;
}
```

The output for this example, which prints both the arrival and departure time, is as follows:

```
LEAVING:  Jul 20 2013  07:30 PM (America/Los_Angeles)
ARRIVING: Jul 21 2013  10:20 PM (Asia/Tokyo)
```

For more details check this page-
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html