# some classes from maven dependency cannot be referenced

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies

I added org.joda.time dependency through maven, and I can reference for example `Seconds` class from `org.joda.time` package but I can't `DateTime` or others. What can cause this behavior? I can browse `joda-time-2.9.9.jar` in Maven Dependencies and all classes are there.

[image]
As you see `Seconds` class is imported as expected but `DateTimeField` is not recognized.

Comment: can you add an example of your code?

Comment: @Yogesh_D I added the screenshot, I think it's more descriptive than code

Comment: Seems weird,  on a separate note, you have a static SDF, its not a thread safe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021151/java-dateformat-is-not-threadsafe-what-does-this-leads-to

Comment: Try Maven -> update or Update Project

Comment: @Yogesh_D i'm just testing out some stuff I also have some business logic in controller as you see :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in corrupted jars. After i deleted joda.time folder from local maven repo and did Maven->Update it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

- First try ALT+F5
- If the error persists, try to build the project from the command line (`mvn clean package`, or through Eclipse as "Run As -> Maven build...").
- If the compilation shows errors, fix them (maybe you need another version of your jar or some other jar shadows the classes you need).

Comment: Did all of the above before I posted here. It's a really weird behavior.