# Adding months to dates

Tags: java, date, calendar, date-formatting, date-parsing

I want to add the number of months based on the duration selected by the user.

I have written the following code, it is taking the current date and adding months based on duration selected by user but I want it to take the start date passed from front end and add the months based on duration.

```
String le=ra.getLease_period(); //duration
String ls=ra.getLeasestart(); // start date

if (le.equals("1"))
{         
    final SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd" );
    final Date dur1 = df.parse( ls ); // conversion from String
    System.out.println("Start date passed is:" + dur1);
    String m = df.format(dur1);
    System.out.println("Formatted dur1 is" + m);
    final java.util.Calendar cal1 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    cal1.setTime( date );
    cal1.add(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, 1 ); // date manipulation
    System.out.println( "result: " + df.format( cal1.getTime() ) ); 
    ra.setLeaseend(df.format( cal1.getTime() ));       
}
```

Comment: Are you limited to Java 7? It's much better to do this using Java 8's `java.time` packages.

Comment: Why are you storing Date in String?

Comment: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/ Joda Time is a fantastic library if you aren't using Java8.

Comment: What is the current output? What is the expected output?

Comment: @RealSkeptic, You can use the `java.time` functionality with Java 7,  which I certainly recommend. See [the **ThreeTen Backport**](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7.

Comment: And Pra, whether you opt for `java.time` in Java 8 or 9, ThreeTen Backport with Java 6 or 7 or Joda-Time, I certainly recommend you scrap the outdated classes `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. The modern alternatives are much nicer to work with and all offer better support for adding a number of months to a date.

Comment: @Adriaan Koster  The current output is if the duration is 1 month it is adding 1 month to current date.  Expected output is if the duration is 1 month it should add that 1 month to the "start date" passed.. I have mentioned start date in the comment in code..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I increment a date by one day in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all for your help.. I resolved the issue by passing the start date in cal1.setTime() function.

```
Calendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar();
cal1.setTime(ra.getLeasestart());
cal1.add(Calendar.MONTH, +1);
Date today1=cal1.getTime();

if(le.equals("1")){

            System.out.println("Lease end date if duratio is 1:"+today1);
            ra.setLeaseend(today1);
        }
// and so one
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. I cannot help noting that the bug you made is one that you couldn’t have made with one of the modern date and time libraries. So repeating myself: get rid of `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Calendar` and start using something less errorprone.

Answer (score 1):

The duration should no be Date. I would say it should be an int (number of months).

```
final Integer dur1 = Integer.parseInt( le ); // conversion from String
final java.util.Calendar cal1 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
cal1.setTime( date );
cal1.add(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, dur1 ); // date manipulation
```

Answer (score 1):

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1571265/7605325) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/7605325), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/7605325).

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, you'll also need the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

First, you can parse the input `String` to a `LocalDate` (using a `DateTimeFormatter`) and then add the specified number of months using the method `plusMonths`. Finally, you format the resulting date with the same formatter:

```
// assuming "le" and "ls" are as described in the question
if (le.equals("1")) {
    // parse the input to a LocalDate
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    LocalDate dt = LocalDate.parse(ls, fmt);
    // add 1 month
    LocalDate nextMonth = dt.plusMonths(Integer.parseInt(le));
    // print it
    System.out.println(fmt.format(nextMonth));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@StanislavL has already answered this... So I'm just providing this to exhibit some simple explorative test wrapping:

```
package time;

import static org.mockito.Matchers.eq;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.spy;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TimeTest {

    @Test
    public void timeInputs1Month() throws ParseException {
        Inputs ra = spy(new Inputs("2017-09-11", "1"));
        stackOverflowQuestion(ra);
        verify(ra).setLeaseend(eq("2017-10-11"));
    }

    @Test
    public void timeInputs12Months() throws ParseException {
        Inputs ra = spy(new Inputs("2017-09-11", "12"));
        stackOverflowQuestion(ra);
        verify(ra).setLeaseend(eq("2018-09-11"));
    }

    private void stackOverflowQuestion(Inputs ra) throws ParseException {
        String le = ra.getLease_period(); //duration
        String ls = ra.getLeasestart(); // start date

        final SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        final Date date = df.parse(ls); // conversion from String
        System.out.println("Start date passed is:" + date);
        final java.util.Calendar cal1 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        cal1.setTime(date);
        cal1.add(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(le)); // date manipulation
        ra.setLeaseend(df.format(cal1.getTime()));
    }

    private class Inputs {

        private final String leaseStart;
        private final String leasePeriod;

        Inputs(String leaseStart, String leasePeriod) {
            this.leaseStart = leaseStart;
            this.leasePeriod = leasePeriod;
        }

        String getLease_period() {
            return leasePeriod;
        }

        String getLeasestart() {
            return leaseStart;
        }

        void setLeaseend(String leaseEnd) {
            System.out.println("result: " + leaseEnd);
        }
    }
}
```

It's also worth noting that the [`SimpleDateFormat` class isn't thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021151/java-dateformat-is-not-threadsafe-what-does-this-leads-to).