# Simple Date format returns Wrong date intermittently

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I am converting Date to string format in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format to save in sqlite database
below is object declared for simple date format

```
public static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Sometime it prepends pair of zeros in date as you can see in below image

Example Wrong date returns as as below

2018-08-25 02:32:0000

2018-08-25 02:32:0049

2018-0008-25 02:32:50

2018-08-24 0023:32:50

2018-08-0024 23:32:50
[image]

I have created custom funtion to correct this wrong date. But I want to know exact cause of this issue.

below is the code

```
public static String getCurrentDateTime() {
    Date d = new Date();

    String datetime = sdf.format(d);
    if (datetime.length() > 19) {
        datetime = correctDate(datetime);
    }
    return datetime;
}
```

Comment: Please include code content for your question, not as pictures.

Comment: Does this behavior always happen?

Comment: Can you please initialize the `sdf` inside the function so that we can have the assurance if the `sdf` has not changed during other operations in your code?

Comment: And what Java version you are using?

Comment: Why you taken SimpleDateFormat as a static?

Comment: @sontruongit This is intermittent issue. Some time it happens

Comment: Probably a result of using the date format in more than one thread. The good solution is to use java.time (through [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP)) and its `DateTimeFormatter`, it is thread safe. If you don’t want to do that, create a separate `SimpleDateFormat` for each thread.

Comment: As an aside, in any case consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure that if you don't use that `static` instance of `SimpleDateFormat` you will have no problem:

```
public static String getCurrentDateTime() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date d = new Date();
    String datetime = sdf.format(d);
    return datetime;
}
```

See these links:  
[Why is Java's SimpleDateFormat not thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840803/why-is-javas-simpledateformat-not-thread-safe)  
["Java DateFormat is not threadsafe" what does this leads to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021151/java-dateformat-is-not-threadsafe-what-does-this-leads-to)

Comment: I am using static variable cause I am converting date in specific time zone. Every user has his own timezone. So he can set time zone of app. So If I use SimpleDateFormat in method then I have to set Time zone as well. It May cause performance issue. So I set TimeZone once application loads and use sdf object to format date

Comment: What performance issue? You're facing a serious problem and you're trying to avoid a simple in method call?

Comment: I have to use   
    SimpleDateFormat sdfLocal = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        sdfLocal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(Utility.TimeZoneId));
will it make any performance issue. As I am picking date every second ??

Comment: I'm not sure that you need it, but if a call that costs less than a millisecond is the only issue then you must make it

Comment: I guess its working dude? I am testing it. I am not sure about performance hit by adding timezone. But its working. Do you know why its adding zeros ?

Comment: What is adding zeros?

Comment: You mean your old static version of SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: Yes. That was returing wrong date e.g 2018-0008-25 02:32:50, 2018-08-24 0023:32:50. Its adding zero before some time day, month, year and some time adding zero to all component of datetime. But I want to know why its behaving like this.

Comment: No I don't know about that. I read 2 or 3 links from SO stating that SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe, so I guess a static instance variable falls in that case too. Otherwise it does not make sense.

Comment: As to why it is behaving that way, the short answer is it wasn’t designed to be thread safe, so when using it from two or more threads, behaviour is unspecified and any result may occur. There’s much more information in the links.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe that's why you should check if in your calling code there is no issue with that.

Comment: Why its adding zero. What is role of threading in adding zeros in date

Comment: Maybe you have to check why it's doing so while multiple threads are accessing the SimpleDateFormat? Is it multiple threaded?