# DateFormatter printed the Date wrongly (Java)

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-format

Why the date printed is `00` instead of `01`?

```
    DateFormat myFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date newDate = myFormatter.parse("01/02/2016"); //assume date today is Feb 01, 2016
    System.out.println(myFormatter.format(newDate));
```

Date printed in the console is: `00/02/2016`

But what i wanted to have is: `01/02/2016`

Please can someone explain what could be gone wrong in my code? 
And how I can fix it?

P.S: February in 2016 having 29 days

Comment: Are you sure?  I can't reproduce your issue, and I can't understand how this might happen.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: *Either* your problem is elsewhere. *Or* it’s a multithreading issue. The old-fashioned `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread-safe, so using it from two or more different threads could easily give this error occassionally. Possible duplicate of [Simple Date format returns Wrong date intermittently \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52000493/simple-date-format-returns-wrong-date-intermittently).

Comment: @OleV.V. yes, its a multi-threaded program. the date variable is passed to 4 other methods. The last three methods showing correct output. but only the first method giving incorrect output. I will try to use DateTimeFormatter.

Comment: I have retracted my vote to close as unreproducible. Now I am not allowed to vote to close as a duplicate of said question, so if others would please do that?

Comment: @Yithirash - that's the kind of detail that you should include in the question - it helps people work out the answer if they know that your program is multi-threaded, and that the problem doesn't happen every time this code is run.  One solution then, is to use a different `SimpleDateFormat` object in each thread.  Another, as others have suggested, is to use `DateTimeFormatter` instead.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, adjusting your existing code to print the parsed version of your input here

```
System.out.println(myFormatter.format(myFormatter.parse("01/02/2016")));
```

prints "01/02/2016" here; check the way you are generating the `Date`. You **could** also try

```
DateFormat myFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US);
```

because there is no telling what `Locale` your system has.

Finally, and arguably one should always do this first, try a debugger.

P.S. In new code you should *prefer* [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). The Java time api is far more consistent.

P.P.S. Not certain why it is relevant, but you are correct that February 2016 has 29 days.

> $ cal 2 2016
>
> ```
>   February 2016
> Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
>     1  2  3  4  5  6
>  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
> 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
> 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
> 28 29
> ```