# SimpleDateFormat parse excepiton and alternative methods differences

Tags: java, multithreading, date, simpledateformat

```
private final static SimpleDateFormat SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyy", Locale.ENGLISH);  //method 1

private static  Date getSimpleDate(String sDate) throws ParseException{
    SimpleDateFormat F = new  SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    System.out.println("pDAte:"+ F.parse(sDate).toString());
    return F.parse(sDate);
} //[method 2]


private static ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> dateFormat = new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>() { 
    @Override
    protected SimpleDateFormat initialValue() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyy", Locale.ENGLISH);// [method 3]
    }
};  //method3

private final static DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER = 
        new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().parseCaseInsensitive()
                                      .appendPattern("ddMMMyy")
                                      .toFormatter();  //[method 4]
```

When I parsed a Date by using method 1 I faced more exception ,

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input at 
java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
```

and

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ".1818E2.1818E2" 
            at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
```

first my question: this value ".1818E2.1818E2" I don't set this value, but I face. Where is coming value. Although I am setting date value  a way correct with correct format,  I face this problem.

But other methods ( method2,method3,method4) is work. and solved the problems. This three method are alternative solution included. 
Second my question, What is among differences this methods.

```
public Date getDscDateAsDate() throws ParseException {
    if(getDscDate()!=null) {
        return SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT.parse(getDscDate());
    }
    return null;                
}
```

Comment: You show the methods, but not the calls.  Could you add those please as that may be where there are issues.

Comment: @JoeG added block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe:

[Why is Java's SimpleDateFormat not thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840803/why-is-javas-simpledateformat-not-thread-safe)

["Java DateFormat is not threadsafe" what does this leads to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021151/java-dateformat-is-not-threadsafe-what-does-this-leads-to)

In method 1, you are using a `SimpleDateFormat` instance in multiple threads, these threads might set some fields of this `SimpleDateFormat` simultaneously, producing invalid intermediate results, such as `.1818E2.1818E2`. You can check the full stack trace of this exception to get more information.

In method 2 and method 3, every thread has its own `SimpleDateFormat` instance. So it's ok.

In method 4, you are using `DateTimeFormatter`, it is thread safe.

Comment: Great pickup - you had to infer that from the question.  Very nice!