# Java SimpleDateFormat is showing incorrect date

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

```
private static final String LONG_DATE_PATTERN = "YYYY-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss a";
private static final SimpleDateFormat longDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(LONG_DATE_PATTERN);

    public static String formatWith12HourClock(Date date) {
        return longDateFormat.format(date);
    }
```

This will produce 2019-Dec-31 12:00:00 AM for date 2018-Dec-31 which is incorrect.

Comment: Can you show how you got the input date?

Comment: Hope this will be helpful: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: You should never have a static `SimpleDateFormat` instance as it is not thread-safe. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021151/java-dateformat-is-not-threadsafe-what-does-this-leads-to

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3):

As said in other answers, you should use `yyyy` instead of `YYYY`. If you are woking with java8 or higher, you can also use `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` to avoid the raw pattern, for example:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR_OF_ERA, 4, 19, SignStyle.EXCEEDS_PAD)
        .appendLiteral("-")
        .appendText(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, TextStyle.SHORT)
        .appendLiteral("-")
        .appendValue(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2)
        .appendLiteral(" ")
        .appendValue(ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM, 2)
        .appendLiteral(":")
        .appendValue(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
        .appendLiteral(":")
        .appendValue(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
        .appendLiteral(" ")
        .appendText(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY, TextStyle.SHORT)
        .toFormatter();

LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println(formatter.format(localDateTime));
```

Answer (score 2):

Change YYYY to yyyy for correct output.
You are getting 2019 as capital 'Y' is Week year. 
Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
Date and Time Patterns

Answer (score 1):

Change Your Format Pattern to yyyy-MM-dd to Obtain 2018-12-31

```
private static final String LONG_DATE_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd";
private static final SimpleDateFormat longDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(LONG_DATE_PATTERN);

    public static String formatWith12HourClock(Date date) {
        return longDateFormat.format(date);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have tried based on OP,

```
public class App {
private static final String LONG_DATE_PATTERN = "yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss a";
private static final String SHORT_DATE_PATTERN = "yyyy-MMM-dd";
    private static final SimpleDateFormat longDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(LONG_DATE_PATTERN);
    private static final SimpleDateFormat shortDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(SHORT_DATE_PATTERN);

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        //Input date 2018-Dec-31 12:00:00 AM
        cal.set(2018, 11, 31, 0, 0, 0);

        Date date = cal.getTime();

        System.out.println(longDateFormat.format(date));
        System.out.println(shortDateFormat.format(date));
}
}
```

output:

> 2018-Dec-31 12:00:00 AM
>
> 2018-Dec-31

There was an issue with your simple date format

- y --> Year
- Y --> Week year

You should Change YYYY with yyyy in Date Pattern.

Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

Use yyyy instead of YYYY since YYYY converts in comparison to weeks in SimpleDateFormat. An average year is exactly 52.1775 weeks long, which means that eventually a year might have either 52 or 53 weeks considering indivisible weeks.

[Don't use YYYY in your date format template](https://www.juandebravo.com/2015/04/10/java-yyyy-date-format/)