# Is org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateFormatUtils.format() thread safe?

Tags: java

I know `org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateFormatUtils.format()` is thread safe, but whats the different between `lang3's DateFormatUtils.format()` and `lang's DateFormatUtils.format()`, is it thread safe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Java DateFormat is not threadsafe" what does this leads to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021151/java-dateformat-is-not-threadsafe-what-does-this-leads-to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is thread safe [DateFormatUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateFormatUtils.html)

> Formatting is performed using the thread-safe FastDateFormat class.