# Java string immutability and NumberFormatException For input string: ""

Tags: java, string, parseint

```java
static Number parse(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.trim().length() == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    return Long.parseLong(s);
}
```

This piece of code intermittently throws `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`.

Running on Java version `11.0.20+8-LTS-sapmachine`.

How is empty string passed into `parseLong`?
I understand `s.trim()` and `s` are different instances but doesn't `s.trim().length() != 0` infer `s` is non-empty?

**UPDATE:**
Apologies, I had left out the fact that I am parsing with a `DecimalFormat` instance (naively thought it did not matter).

```java
static java.text.DecimalFormat df = new java.text.DecimalFormat("#");

static Number parse(String s) throws java.text.ParseException {
    if (s == null || s.trim().length() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return df.parse(s);
}
```

This code throws `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""` from time to time on a *live server*. Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:702)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:817)
    at java.text.DigitList.getLong(DigitList.java:195)
    at java.text.DecimalFormat.parse(DecimalFormat.java:2121)
    at java.text.NumberFormat.parse(NumberFormat.java:429)
```

Comment: What is the value of `s` when this error is thrown?

Comment: Is your question, how to write a method that returns the length of a trimmed String?

Comment: The point of this function is to prevent NumberFormatException from getting thrown? I think better to not have this function and catch NumberFormatException in places where you'd otherwise be calling it.

Comment: Can't reproduce with the empty string (`""`); if I pass the empty string to `parse`, I correctly get `0`. Just because a string renders like the empty string does not mean that it is the empty string; it may contain invisible zero-width Unicode characters (such as a zero-width space), which `trim` doesn't trim.

Comment: Yes, I can catch the NumberFormatException. It is an easy solution however I am trying to understand how I am getting the empty string in the first place.

Comment: The value of `s` is set by `String.valueOf(a non-null BigDecimal object)`. Can `BigDecimal#toString` return an invisible character?

Comment: Welcome. Best for getting useful advice is follow the Help guidance to provide a minimum executable example of the problem.  nb: one method to debug this is to trap NumberException in a debugger so you can inspect the value of `s` that caused it. It's fairly likely that what you think is happening is not really.

Comment: I don't see how this would happen considering you test _s.trim().length()_.  Are you sure the _NumberFormatException_ stems from this code?

Comment: String.valueOf(BigDecimal) cannot return null and cannot return a blank String.  You shouldn’t even need to test for those values.  Try adding `System.out.println(s.length());` right before you call Long.parseLong.  That will tell us whether your string is really empty.

Comment: Yes, the exception is coming from the parse function but I may have left out a critical information while trying to simplify the snippet. Updating the question.

Comment: `Long#parseLong` and `DecimalFormat#parse` are two very different functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Number parse(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
  if (s == null || s.isBlank()) {
    return 0;
  }
  return Long.parseLong(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking into `DigitList` class, `s` definitely is not the input string here.
The `DigitList`'s use of `StringBuffer tempBuffer` is not thread-safe.

```java
private StringBuffer getStringBuffer() {
    if (tempBuffer == null) {
        tempBuffer = new StringBuffer(MAX_COUNT);
    } else {
        tempBuffer.setLength(0);
    }
    return tempBuffer;
}
```

`tempBuffer.setLength(0)` is what is causing the empty input string.
`DecimalFormat.digitList` and `DigitList.tempBuffer` are both class members and I am using a singleton `DecimalFormat` instance creating a race condition.

I am able to reproduce the problem with this line of code

```java
IntStream
  .range(1, Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 3)
  .parallel()
  .forEach(s -> parse("123"));
```

Without the `parallel()` mode, the issue does not occur.

Having found the root of the issue, I also found this question is essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/4021932/22569932 where good explanation and solution are provided.